# Многопоточность и ArrayList

Tags: java, многопоточность, arraylist

Существует `ArrayList`, который в себе содержит ссылки на файлы для скачивания. Существует метод `downloadFile` который может скачать эти файлы.

Кусок кода:

```
 for (String i : arrayList) {
     downloadFile(i);
 }
```

позволяет скачать все ссылки по очереди

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно запустить скачку в несколько потоков?

Comment: Запускайте в цикле потоки, сделайте после цикла join, делов-то!

Comment: @VladD в том то и проблема, я не совсем понимаю как правильно написать сам поток, как их запустить я понимаю

Answer (score 7):

Эх, всё вам разжевать надо. А вы [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) читали?

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (String s : arrayList) {
    final String finalS = s; // у Java замыкания слабоваты, нужна копия
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            downloadFile(finalS);
        }
    };
    threads.add(thread);
    thread.start();
}

for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/4L6nNM

Comment: Примерно это вариант я знал как сделать
но если я правильно понимаю, то будет создано такое количество потоков, сколько элементов у меня в ArrayList

а если мне нужно создать например только 10 потоков? а элементов в ArrayList у меня 50
и зациклить выполнение потоков пока они не выберут ArrayList

Comment: @elite_kr: Тогда вам нужен вариант [producer-consumer queue](/research/221526/).

Comment: Обновленная ссылка: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-producer-consumer-pattern

Comment: Воспользуйтесь исполнителем с фиксированным пулом потоков. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` и скармливаете в него Runnable. (см. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html и https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/executorservice/java-executorservice-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант, вот такое решение:

```
int threadCount = 10;
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

for (String s : arrayList)
    executorService.submit(() -> downloadFile(s));

executorService.shutdown();
while (executorService.isTerminated() 
           && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

`arrayList.parallelStream().forEach(f -> f.downloadFile(f));`

выполняет в нескольких потоках и качает параллельно

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте библиотеку java.util.concurrent, с помощью нее можно организовать пул потоков и там некоторые вещи неплохо оптимизированы.больше о ее возможностях можно узнать [тут](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/index.html)