# Реализация паттерна Producer/Consumer

Tags: многопоточность, асинхронность, шаблоны-проектирования, очередь-задач

Паттерн producer/consumer достаточно часто встречается в многопоточном программировании. Его смысл состоит в том, что один или несколько потоков *производят* данные, и параллельно этому один или несколько потоков *потребляют* их.

**Как правильно реализовать этот паттерн в популярных языках программирования?** Задача сама по себе нетривиальна, поскольку включает синхронизацию между потоками, и потенциальную гонку между несколькими производителями и потребителями.

---

**Справка.**

Производящий поток (или потоки) называется «производитель», «поставщик» или просто «producer», потребляющий (-ие) — «потребитель» или «consumer».

Нетривиальность проблемы заключается в том, что потенциально как создание новых данных, так и их потребление могут занимать длительное время, и хотелось бы, чтобы обработка шла без простоев, на максимально возможной скорости.

Примеры:

Произведённые данные могут представлять вычислительно интенсивное *задание*. В этом случае разумно иметь единственный производящий поток, и несколько выполняющих потоков (например, столько, сколько в системе ядер процессора, если узкое место обработки — вычисления).

Или производящие потоки загружают данные из сети, а по окончанию загрузки выполняющие потоки производит разбор загруженных данных. В этом случае разумно иметь по одному производителю на сайт и, и ограничивать число производителей, если предел доступной скорости сети исчерпан.

---

Этот вопрос — адаптация одноименного исследования с Хэшкода.

Comment: Не машало б еще для полноты картины про poison pill рассказать, как альтернативу явной остановке.

Comment: @andreycha: Может, вы напишете отдельным ответом? Потому что я не знаю, как скалировать poison pill на случай нескольких консьюмеров. (И нескольких продюсеров, кстати, тоже.)

Answer (score 21):

## Реализация на C#

Для современных версий языка (начиная с C# 4.0), имеет смысл не писать реализацию вручную, а (руководствуясь советом @Flammable), [воспользоваться классом `BlockingCollection`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT), представляющим нужную функциональность.

Для чтения в consumer-потоках используем просто циклы по последовательности, которую даёт `GetConsumingEnumerable()`. В producer-потоках пользуемся `Add`, и в конце не забываем `CompleteAdding`, чтобы consumer-потоки смогли остановиться.

Пример:

```
class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    BlockingCollection<string> q = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    void Run()
    {
        var threads = new [] { new Thread(Consumer), new Thread(Consumer) };
        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Start();

        string s;
        while ((s = Console.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
            q.Add(s);

        q.CompleteAdding(); // останавливаем

        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Join();
    }

    void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var s in q.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0}", s);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Processed: {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```

`BlockingCollection<T>` позволяет [ограничить количество элементов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), так что попытка добавить элемент в переполненную очередь также может быть заблокирована до освобождения места.

Заметьте, что `GetConsumingEnumerable` корректно работает даже в случае, когда у вас много консьюмеров. Это не так уж и очевидно.

---

Если вы работаете со старой версией C#, вам придётся писать нужную функциональность вручную. Вы можете воспользоваться встроенным классом `Monitor` (который является аналогом mutex + condition variable из pthreads).

```
public class ProducerConsumer<T> where T : class
{
    object mutex = new object();
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    bool isDead = false;

    public void Enqueue(T task)
    {
        if (task == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
        lock (mutex)
        {
            if (isDead)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue already stopped");
            queue.Enqueue(task);
            Monitor.Pulse(mutex);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            while (queue.Count == 0 && !isDead)
                Monitor.Wait(mutex);

            if (queue.Count == 0)
                return null;

            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            isDead = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(mutex);
        }
    }
}
```

Использование (аналогичный пример):

```
class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    ProducerConsumer<string> q = new ProducerConsumer<string>();

    void Run()
    {
        var threads = new [] { new Thread(Consumer), new Thread(Consumer) };
        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Start();

        string s;
        while ((s = Console.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
            q.Enqueue(s);

        q.Stop();

        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Join();
    }

    void Consumer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string s = q.Dequeue();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0}", s);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Processed: {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, упоминание про BlockingCollection стоило бы поставить до самописной версии

Comment: @PashaPash: Разумно. Так и сделаю.

Comment: *"Вы можете воспользоваться встроенным классом Monitor (который является аналогом condition variable из pthreads)."* - формулировка не совсем точная. Монитор - это аналог связки mutex + condition variable.

Comment: И хорошо бы еще ProducerConsumer<T> сделать реализующим IDisposable.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм. А что должен в этом случае делать `Dispose`?

Comment: Вызыаать Stop, что же еще он может сделать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм. Пытаюсь сообразить, есть ли у `Stop` семантика уничтожения объекта. `ProducerConsumer<T>` позволяет вызывать `Dequeue` после `Stop`.

Comment: Зато `Enqueue` вызвать уже нельзя...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Это да. На самом деле, `Stop` оказалось прямым аналогом `CompleteAdding()` из `BlockingCollection` (хотя писалось независимо).

Comment: Угу. Кстати, метод `Dispose()` у `BlockingCollection` есть, но делает совсем другое... Так что теперь и не знаю.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Тогда пусть читатель читает комментарии и думает сам.

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем здесь два потока которые вызывают один и тот же метод... Как бы это выглядело если бы у нас был метод который считает допустим а+b, второй поток, в котором метод, который выводит этот результат на экран?

Comment: Так, окей, я понял, что у нас есть очередь потоков основной, 1 и 2. вызываются по очереди, этой очередью "управляет" наша коллекция, НО, я не понимаю до сих пор, как же мне реализовать, что бы в двух созданных потоках, в 1 производить расчёты и записывать в коллекцию, а в 2 потоке выводить эту информацию на консоль((((

Comment: @Valera: У нас два consumer-потока, которые параллельно разгребают очередь заданий. Для чего такое может понадобиться? Ну например, если заданий много, и обработка одного задания медленная, то в два потока мы вдвое быстрее всё завершим.

Comment: @Valera: Для случая выведения на экран особого выигрыша нет. Но если consumer делает нетривиальную, длинную работу, то в нескольких consumer'ах сразу появляется смысл.

Comment: @VladD, да я понял, спасибо, посидел попробовал разные вариации, и понял. Извините за следующий вопрос. Я пытаюсь понять как реализовать примерно такую задачу: у нас есть формула а*2, это значение рассчитывает один созданный поток и записывает в массив. 2 поток берет значения из массива и выводит. Согласно вашему примеру отлично все получилось!! И огромное вам спасибо. Но не могу понять, как это реализовать с двумя созданными потоками(

Comment: @Valera: А какие именно потоки вам нужны? Вот пример с одним producer'ом и двумя consumer'ами: https://pastebin.com/pX8v63c9

Answer (score 17):

## Реализация на C с библиотекой pthreads

В C, в соответствии с духом языка, нет встроенных высокоуровневых синхронизирующихся коллекций. Наверное самой популярной и широко используемой библиотекой, реализующей многопоточность, является pthreads. С её помощью паттерн можно реализовать так:

```
#include <pthread.h>

// объявляем структуру данных для одного задания
struct producer_consumer_queue_item {
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *next;
  // здесь идут собственно данные. вы можете поменять этот кусок,
  // использовав структуру, более специфичную для вашей задачи
  void *data;
};

// объявляем очередь с дополнительными структурами для синхронизации.
// в этой очереди будут храниться произведённые, но ещё не потреблённые задания.
struct producer_consumer_queue {
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *head, *tail;
                              // head == tail == 0, если очередь пуста
  pthread_mutex_t lock;       // мьютекс для всех манипуляций с очередью
  pthread_cond_t cond;        // этот cond "сигналим", когда очередь стала НЕ ПУСТОЙ
  int is_alive;               // показывает, не закончила ли очередь свою работу
};
```

Теперь нам нужны процедуры добавления и извлечения заданий из очереди.

```
void
enqueue (void *data, struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  // упакуем задание в новую структуру
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
  p->data = data;
  p->next = 0;

  // получим "эксклюзивный" доступ к очереди заданий
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
  // ... и добавим новое задание туда:
  if (q->tail)
    q->tail->next = p;
  else {
    q->head = p;
    // очередь была пуста, а теперь нет -- надо разбудить потребителей
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond);
  }
  q->tail = p;

  // разрешаем доступ всем снова
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
}

void *
dequeue(struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  // получаем эксклюзивный доступ к очереди:
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);

  while (!q->head && q->is_alive) {
    // очередь пуста, делать нечего, ждем...
    pthread_cond_wait(&q->cond, &q->lock);
    // wait разрешает доступ другим на время ожидания
  }

  // запоминаем текущий элемент или 0, если очередь умерла
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = q->head;

  if (p)
  {
    // и удаляем его из очереди
    q->head = q->head->next;
    if (!q->head)
      q->tail = q->head;
  }

  // возвращаем эксклюзивный доступ другим участникам
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);

  // отдаём данные
  void *data = p ? p->data : 0; // 0 означает, что данных больше не будет
  free(p);
  return data;
}
```

Ещё нужна процедура для инициализации очереди:

```
struct producer_consumer_queue *
producer_consumer_queue_create()
{
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = (typeof(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
  q->head = q->tail = 0;
  q->is_alive = 1;
  pthread_mutex_init(&q->lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&q->cond, 0);

  return q;
}
```

И процедура для закрытия очереди:

```
void
producer_consumer_queue_stop(struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  // для обращения к разделяемым переменным необходим эксклюзивный доступ
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
  q->is_alive = 0;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
}
```

Отлично, у нас есть всё, что нам надо.

Как использовать это? Нужно:

- запустить несколько потоков-«производителей» и несколько «потребителей»
- придумать структуру данных для задания

Пример: (производитель — главный поток, потребители — 2 потока)

```
// это поток-потребитель
void *
consumer_thread (void *arg)
{
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = (typeof(q))arg;

  for (;;) {
    void *data = dequeue(q);
    // это сигнал, что очередь окончена
    if (!data)
      break; // значит, пора закрывать поток

    char *str = (char *)data;
    // тут наша обработка данных
    printf ("consuming: %s\n", str);
    sleep(2);
    printf ("consumed: %s\n", str);
    free(str);
  }
  return 0;
}

int
main ()
{
  pthread_t consumer_threads[2];

  void *res = 0;

  char *in = NULL;
  size_t sz;

  // создадим очередь:
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = producer_consumer_queue_create();

  // и потоки-«потребители»
  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[0], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);
  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[1], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);

  // главный цикл
  // получаем данные с клавиатуры:
  while (getline(&in, &sz, stdin) > 0) {
    enqueue(in, q);
    in = NULL;
  }

  producer_consumer_queue_stop(q);
  if (pthread_join(consumer_threads[0], &res) ||
      pthread_join(consumer_threads[1], &res))
    perror("join");

  return (long)res;
}
```

Это реализация задачи с "бесконечной" очередью. На практике же иногда (или почти всегда?) более полезно ограничить размер очереди и таким образом сбалансировать скорость производителей, иногда переводя их в спящее состояние, с возможностями потребителей.

Для этого немного изменим нашу `producer_consumer_queue`

```
struct producer_consumer_queue {
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *head, *tail;
                              // head == tail == 0, если очередь пуста
  pthread_mutex_t lock;       // мьютекс для всех манипуляций с очередью
  pthread_cond_t condp;       // этот cond "сигналим", когда очередь стала НЕ ПУСТОЙ
  pthread_cond_t condc;       // этот cond "сигналим", когда в очереди ПОЯВИЛОСЬ СВОБОДНОЕ МЕСТО
  int is_alive;               // показывает, не закончила ли очередь свою работу
  int max, cnt,               // максимальный размер очереди и число заданий в ней
    pqcnt;                    // количество производителей, ждущих свободного места в очереди
};
```

Добавляем `pthread_cond_t condc` для "засыпания/пробуждения" потоков производителей, их счетчик в очереди на отправку сообщения и пару переменных, содержащих максимальный размер очереди и текущее количество заданий в ней.

Соответственно меняются функции для постановки задания в очередь (`enqueue`), выборки его из очереди (`dequeue`), инициализации очереди (`producer_consumer_queue_create`) и ее остановки (`producer_consumer_queue_stop`):

```
void
enqueue (void *data, struct producer_consumer_queue *aq)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *q = aq;
  // упакуем задание в новую структуру
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
  p->data = data;
  p->next = 0;

  // получим "эксклюзивный" доступ к очереди заданий
  pthread_mutex_lock(&aq->lock);

  // проверим не переполнена ли она
  if (q->max <= q->cnt) {
    q->pqcnt++;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
    // зафиксируем изменения очереди в памяти
    // будем ждать пока потребители ее слегка не опустошат 
    while(q->max <= q->cnt & q->is_alive)
      pthread_cond_wait(&aq->condc, &aq->lock);
    q->pqcnt--;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
  }
  // ... и добавим новое задание туда:
  if (q->tail)
    q->tail->next = p;
  else {
    q->head = p;
    // очередь была пуста, а теперь нет -- надо разбудить потребителей
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&aq->condp);
  }
  q->tail = p;
  q->cnt++;
  asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");

  // разрешаем доступ всем снова
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&aq->lock);
}


void *
dequeue(struct producer_consumer_queue *aq)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *q = aq;
  // получаем эксклюзивный доступ к очереди:
  pthread_mutex_lock(&aq->lock);

  if (q->pqcnt && q->max > q->cnt)
    // в очереди есть место, а кто-то спит, разбудим их
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&aq->condc);

  while (!q->head && q->is_alive) {
    // очередь пуста, делать нечего, ждем...
    pthread_cond_wait(&aq->condp, &aq->lock);
    // wait разрешает доступ другим на время ожидания
  }

  // запоминаем текущий элемент или 0, если очередь умерла
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = q->head;
  if (p) {
    // и удаляем его из очереди
    q->head = q->head->next;
    if (!q->head)
      q->tail = q->head;
    q->cnt--;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
    // зафиксируем изменения очереди в памяти
    // разбудим поставщиков в их очереди
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&aq->condc);
  }

  // возвращаем эксклюзивный доступ другим участникам
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&aq->lock);

  // отдаём данные
  void *data = p ? p->data : 0; // 0 означает, что данных больше не будет
  free(p);
  return data;
}

struct producer_consumer_queue * 
producer_consumer_queue_create(int max)
{
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = (typeof(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
  q->head = q->tail = 0;
  q->is_alive = 1;
  q->max = max;
  q->cnt = 0;
  q->pqcnt = 0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&q->lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&q->condc, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&q->condp, 0);

  return q;
}

// И процедура для закрытия очереди:

void
producer_consumer_queue_stop(struct producer_consumer_queue *aq)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *q = aq;
  // для обращения к разделяемым переменным необходим эксклюзивный доступ
  pthread_mutex_lock(&aq->lock);
  q->is_alive = 0;
  asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&aq->condc);
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&aq->condp);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&aq->lock);
}
```

Здесь же показан [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) (`asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");`), использование которого запрещает компилятору переупорядочивать операции чтения-записи из RAM.

Данная реализация не обеспечивает "упорядоченность" производителей, ожидающих своей очереди для отправки сообщения. Т.е. поток производитель, "заснувший" первым из-за отсутствия свободного места в очереди не обязательно проснется первым.

Если такое поведение нас не устраивает, то придется внести некоторые изменения в наши данные, прежде всего добавив очередь поставщиков из структур `producer_queue_item` (которая будет частью структуры `producer_consumer_queue`.

Получаем следующие структуры данных:

```
// объявляем структуру данных для одного задания
struct producer_consumer_queue_item {
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *next;
  // здесь идут собственно данные. вы можете поменять этот кусок,
  // использовав структуру, более специфичную для вашей задачи
  void *data;
};

// струкура данных для спящего (ждущего свободного места) потока-производителя
struct producer_queue_item {
  struct producer_queue_item *next;
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *item; // данные для которых нет места
  pthread_cond_t cond;  // этот cond "сигналим", когда в очереди появилось место

#if DEBUG
  pid_t tid;    // linux thread id for debug print
  int signaled; // индикатор "побудки" for debug print
#endif
};

// объявляем очередь данных с дополнительными структурами для синхронизации.
// в этой очереди будут храниться произведённые, но ещё не потреблённые задания.
struct producer_consumer_queue {
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *head, *tail;
                              // head == tail == 0, если очередь пуста
  pthread_mutex_t lock;       // мьютекс для всех манипуляций с очередью
  pthread_cond_t cond;        // этот cond "сигналим", когда очередь стала НЕ ПУСТОЙ
  int is_alive;               // показывает, не закончила ли очередь свою работу
  int max, cnt;               // максимальный размер очереди и число заданий в ней
  // очередь  потоков-производителей, ждущих свободного места для своих данных
  struct producer_queue_item *pqhead,
    *pqtail;
};
```

и реализацию основных функций:

```
void
enqueue (void *data, struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *vq = q;
  // упакуем задание в новую структуру
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
  p->data = data;
  p->next = 0;

  // получим "эксклюзивный" доступ к очереди заданий
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);

#if DEBUG
  printf("%ld (cnt: %d) ---> %s", (long)gettid(), vq->cnt, (char *)(p->data));
#endif

  // ... и добавим новое задание туда:
  if (vq->max <= vq->cnt || vq->pqtail) {// производитель должен ждать

#if DEBUG
    if (vq->cnt < vq->max) {
      puts("========================");
      print_queue(q, 0);
      puts("========================");
    }
#endif

    struct producer_queue_item *pq = (typeof(pq))malloc(sizeof(*pq));
    pthread_cond_init(&pq->cond, 0);  // cond по которому его разбудят
    pq->next = 0;
    pq->item = p;  // сохраним данные на время сна

#if DEBUG
    pq->tid = gettid();
#endif

    // поместим себя в очередь спящих производителей
    if (vq->pqtail)
      vq->pqtail->next = pq;
    else
      vq->pqhead = pq;
    vq->pqtail = pq;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
    // зафиксируем изменения очереди в памяти

#if DEBUG
    int at = 0; // счетчик циклов пробуждения
#endif

    do { // пойдем спать до появления свободного места в очереди данных

#if DEBUG
      printf ("%ld prod cond wait (cnt: %d  at: %d) %s", 
          (long)gettid(), vq->cnt, at++, (char *)(p->data));
      pq->signaled = 0;
#endif

      pthread_cond_wait(&pq->cond, &q->lock);
    } while(vq->max <= vq->cnt && vq->is_alive);
    // проснулись и владеем очередью

    /*
      Вот тонкий момент. Порядок активизации потоков не определен,
      а нам надо соблюдать очередность данных.
      Поэтому переустановим локальные переменные из очереди, 
      хотя это могут быть данные, положенные туда другим потоком.
    */
#if DEBUG
    if (pq != vq->pqhead) {
      printf ("BAAAD %ld (cnt: %d  at: %d) %s",
          (long)gettid(), vq->cnt, at, (char *)(p->data));
      print_queue(q, 0);
      if (vq->is_alive)
    exit(1); // совсем плохо, такого быть не должно
      else
    puts("CONTINUE");
    }
#endif

    pq = vq->pqhead;  // в любом случае берем голову очереди производителей
    if ((vq->pqhead = pq->next) == 0) // и удаляем ее
      vq->pqtail = 0;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
    p = pq->item;
    free(pq);

#if DEBUG
    printf ("%ld prod enqueued after wait (cnt: %d  at: %d) %s", 
        (long)gettid(), vq->cnt, at, (char *)(p->data));    
#endif

  }

  // вот тут реально кладем data в очередь для потребителей
  if (vq->tail)
    vq->tail->next = p;
  else {
    vq->head = p;
    // очередь была пуста, а теперь нет -- надо разбудить потребителей
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond);
  }
  vq->tail = p;
  vq->cnt++;
  asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
  // сбросим изменения очереди в память

  // разрешаем доступ всем снова
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
}

#if DEBUG                   
#define cond_signal_producer(q) ({          \
      if ((q)->pqhead) {                \
      (q)->pqhead->signaled = 1;            \
      pthread_cond_signal(&(q)->pqhead->cond);  \
      }                         \
    })
#else
#define cond_signal_producer(q) ({          \
      if ((q)->pqhead)                  \
      pthread_cond_signal(&(q)->pqhead->cond);  \
    })
#endif

void *
dequeue(struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *vq = q;

  // получаем эксклюзивный доступ к очереди:
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);

  // если есть спящие производители, то разбудим первого
  cond_signal_producer(vq);  
  while (!vq->head && vq->is_alive) {
    // очередь пуста, делать нечего, ждем...
    pthread_cond_wait(&q->cond, &q->lock);
    // wait разрешает доступ другим на время ожидания
  }

  // запоминаем текущий элемент или 0, если очередь умерла
  struct producer_consumer_queue_item *p = vq->head;
  if (p) {
    // и удаляем его из очереди
    vq->head = vq->head->next;
    if (!vq->head)
      vq->tail = vq->head;
    vq->cnt--;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
    // сбросим изменения очереди в память
    // разбудим первого поставщика в их очереди
    cond_signal_producer(vq);
  }

  // возвращаем эксклюзивный доступ другим участникам
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);

  // отдаём данные
  void *data = p ? p->data : 0; // 0 означает, что данных больше не будет
  // согласно 7.20.3.2/2, можно не проверять на 0
  free(p);
  return data;
}

struct producer_consumer_queue * 
producer_consumer_queue_create(int max)
{
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = (typeof(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
  q->head = q->tail = 0;
  q->pqhead = q->pqtail = 0;
  q->is_alive = 1;
  q->max = max;
  q->cnt = 0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&q->lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&q->cond, 0);

  return q;
}

// И процедура для закрытия очереди:

void
producer_consumer_queue_stop(struct producer_consumer_queue *q)
{
  volatile struct producer_consumer_queue *vq = q;
  // для обращения к разделяемым переменным необходим эксклюзивный доступ
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);

  vq->is_alive = 0;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond); // разбудим потребителей
  volatile struct producer_queue_item *pq;
  for (pq = vq->pqhead; pq; pq = pq->next) {
#if DEBUG
    pq->signaled = 1;
    asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");
#endif
    // будим каждого ждущего производителя
    pthread_cond_signal((pthread_cond_t *)&pq->cond);
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
}
```

Все три программы (pq1.c, pq2.c и pq3.c) вместе с функцией `gettid()` находятся в http://pastebin.com/E23r9DZk . Для экспериментов скопируйте их в разные файлы и компилируйте, например, `gcc pq3.c -pthread gettid.o`

Answer (score 14):

## Реализация на C#, библиотека Dataflow

Ещё одной альтернативой является использование Майкрософтовской библиотеки [Dataflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), которая собственно и создана для того, чтобы управлять потоками данных. Для использования кода в примерах, вам нужно подключить NuGet-пакет <del>Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow</del> [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/). Класс [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) практически является готовым producer/consumer'ом, но, в отличие от блокирующего интерфейса `BlockingCollection<T>`, он имеет async-интерфейс!

Для асинхронного добавления задания поставщик может воспользоваться `SendAsync`. Асинхронное добавление нужно, так как очередь может быть ограниченной длины, а значит, добавление должно будет дожидаться наличия свободного места! По окончанию добавления нужно вызвать `Complete`.

```
async Task ProduceSingle(ITargetBlock<string> queue, int howmuch)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (howmuch-- > 0)
    {
        // эмулируем длительную работу по подготовке следующего задания
        // длительность выбираем случайно, чтобы задания приходили в
        // непредсказуемые моменты времени
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
        var v = string.Format("automatic {0}", r.Next(1, 10));
        await queue.SendAsync(v);
    }
    queue.Complete();
}
```

Если у вас несколько поставщиков, закрывать очередь нужно лишь когда они все отработают:

```
async Task Produce1(ITargetBlock<string> queue, int howmuch)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (howmuch-- > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
        var v = string.Format("automatic {0}", r.Next(1, 10));
        await queue.SendAsync(v);
    }
}

// функция Console.ReadLine() -- блокирующая, поэтому выполняем её асинхронно
// (иначе она заблокирует вызывающий поток)
// у Console нет async-интерфейса.
Task<string> ReadConsole()
{
    // блокирующую функцию выгружаем в thread pool
    return Task.Run(() => Console.ReadLine());
}

async Task Produce2(ITargetBlock<string> queue)
{
    string s;
    while ((s = await ReadConsole()).Length != 0)
        await queue.SendAsync("manual " + s);
}

async Task ProduceAll(ITargetBlock<string> queue)
{
    var p1 = Produce1(queue, 20);
    var p2 = Produce2(queue);
    await Task.WhenAll(p1, p2);
    queue.Complete();
}
```

Теперь, потребитель. Если потребитель лишь один, всё просто:

```
async Task ConsumeSingle(ISourceBlock<string> queue)
{
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
        Console.WriteLine(await queue.ReceiveAsync());
}
```

Для случая нескольких потребителей использовать `ReceiveAsync` — неверно, так как [задание может быть взято из очереди другим потребителем](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)! Функции `TryReceiveAsync` тоже нету, поэтому после асинхронного выяснения того, что очередь не пуста, используем `TryReceive`:

```
async Task ConsumeCooperative(IReceivableSourceBlock<string> queue, int number)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        string v;
        // в этой точке данные могут быть уже уйти другому потребителю
        if (!queue.TryReceive(out v))
            continue; // продолжаем ждать

        // цветной вывод и прочие плюшки
        // мне лень синхронизировать вывод на консоль, хотя конечно это разделяемый ресурс
        if (Console.CursorLeft != 0)
            Console.WriteLine();
        var savedColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)(number + 8);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}[{1}]: {2}",
                          new string(' ', number * 4), number, v));
        Console.ForegroundColor = savedColor;

        // симулируем длительную обработку результата клиентом
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
    }
}

Task ConsumeAll(IReceivableSourceBlock<string> queue)
{
    var c1 = ConsumeCooperative(queue, 1);
    var c2 = ConsumeCooperative(queue, 2);
    return Task.WhenAll(c1, c2);
}
```

Осталась обвязка:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().RunAll().Wait();
    }

    async Task RunAll()
    {
        BufferBlock<string> queue = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var p = ProduceAll(queue);
        var c = ConsumeAll(queue);
        await Task.WhenAll(p, c, queue.Completion);
    }

    // остальные методы
}
```

---

В своей статье [*Async Producer/Consumer Queue using Dataflow*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html) Stephen Cleary предлагает другой подход, более в духе библиотеки Dataflow. В ней заложена симметрия между блоками-источниками (`ISourceBlock<T>`), блоками-приёмниками (`ITargetBlock<T>`), и блоками-преобразователями (`IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>`). В соответствии с этой идеологией, мы применяем для поставщика блок-приёмник [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Task Consume2(ISourceBlock<string> queue, int number)
{
    var consumerOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 };
    var consumer = new ActionBlock<string>(v => ConsumeImpl2(v, number), consumerOptions);
    var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
    queue.LinkTo(consumer, linkOptions);
    return consumer.Completion;
}

void ConsumeImpl2(string v, int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}]: {1}", number, v));
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
}

Task ConsumeAll2(ISourceBlock<string> queue)
{
    var c1 = Consume2(queue, 1);
    var c2 = Consume2(queue, 2);
    return Task.WhenAll(c1, c2);
}
```

Для чего нужно `BoundedCapacity = 1`? Дел в том, что по умолчанию `ActionBlock<T>` имеет «неограниченную» ёмкость, и таким образом за раз потребит все данные из очереди. Таким образом, если мы ввели ограничение на объём очереди

```
queue = new BufferBlock<string>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 20 });
```

то данные будут всё равно накапливаться в `ActionBlock`'е. Чтобы роль хранилища исполнялась `BufferBlock`'ом, а потребителя — `ActionBlock`, и нужно ограничить его объём. Заметьте также, что ограничение ёмкости `ActionBlock`'а позволяет библиотеке Dataflow балансировать нагрузку, отправляя данные свободному блоку.

Заметьте, что в этом случае то, в каком контексте (пул потоков? выделенный поток?) исполняется `ActionBlock`, управляется не через стандартный механизм async/await, а посредством [`TaskScheduler`'а в настройках](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Подход со стыковкой блоков выполнения может быстро стать слишком тяжеловесным, поэтому я советовал бы использовать его лишь для достаточно сложных задач.

Comment: В цикле, основанном на `await queue.OutputAvailableAsync() + TryReceive` в случае малого потока данных от поставщиков все потребители будут пробуждаться одновременно - что негативно скажется на времени. По мне - так лучше использовать `await ReceiveAsync` и перехватывать исключение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Надеюсь, что в C# доставят таки аналог Go channels с select'ом ([обговаривалось здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5383)), тогда такие рассмотрения переместятся в плоскость ответственности разработчиков BCL.

Comment: Там больше про паттерн-матчинг в операторе `select` писалось. Все-таки Go channels слишком высокоуровневые, чтобы вводить оператор для них на уровне языка.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Практически, Go channel — это и есть producer-consumer-очередь с async-интерфейсом. Довольно хорошо ложится на семантику .NET, как мне кажется.

Comment: Вот только я, к примеру, за последний год ни разу не писал "чистый" producer-consumer, всюду были тонкости, которые go channels не покроют.

Comment: Одно дело, когда producer-consumer является основным примитивом языка, да еще и разделяемых данных нету - это круто. Другое дело, когда producer-consumer является лишь одним из паттернов

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, producer-consumer — это, на мой взгляд, примитив, который должен быть в языке, ориентированном на асинхронность. Неудивительно, что в чистом виде он слишком простой и нуждается в конфигурации и допиливании. Вот ещё и immutable-классы подтянутся, будет совсем хорошо.

Answer (score 7):

### Реализация на C#, библиотека Dataflow ("инверсный" алгоритм)

Отличие данного алгоритма от приведенного VladD ["прямого"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431145/178779) - в том, что используется очередь потребителей вместо очереди элементов.

Это позволяет избавиться от цикла приема в потребителе - ценой появления знания списка потребителей поставщиком данных. Иными словами, в такой конфигурации потребители выходят не активными - а пассивными.

Кроме того, сам алгоритм получается очень простым.

Потребитель в таком алгоритме не имеет никакого алгоритма, это лишь класс (или интерфейс либо вовсе делегат), в котором можно вызвать метод:

```
class Consumer
{
  public void Consume(string str)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

На стороне поставщика алгоритм немного сложнее:

```
BufferBlock<Consumer> consumers = new BufferBlock<Consumer>();

public async void SendToConsumer(string str)
{
  var consumer = await consumers.ReceiveAsync();
  try
  {
    consumer.Consume(str);
  }
  finally
  {
    consumers.Post(consumer);
  }
}

async Task Produce(int howmuch)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (howmuch-- > 0)
    {
        // эмулируем длительную работу по подготовке следующего задания
        // длительность выбираем случайно, чтобы задания приходили в
        // непредсказуемые моменты времени
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
        var v = string.Format("automatic {0}", r.Next(1, 10));
        SendToConsumer(v);
    }
}
```

К сожалению, это еще не все. Дело в том, что в таком виде любое исключение, возникшее в методе Consume, обрушит программу.

Поэтому надо сделать одну из двух вещей:

- добавить в метод контракт класса `Consumer` требование обязательной обработки исключений;
- или же установить глобальный обработчик неперехваченных исключений.

А еще лучше - воспользоваться сразу обоими вариантами.

И еще один важный момент. Пассивность потребителя означает, в частности, что потребитель будет запущен в контексте синхронизации поставщика. Иногда это может быть нежелательным - в таком случае в код `SendToConsumer` следует добавить вызов `Task.Run`.

Иногда же, напротив, производителю нужно дождаться полной обработки порции данных. В таком случае надо сменить возвращаемое значение у метода `SendToConsumer` с `void` на `Task`.

Comment: Я не знаю шарп, поэтому не судите строго. Правильно ли я понял, что реальные потоки ОС (в которых выполняется функция `Consume()`) будут создаваться вызовом `SendToConsumer()`, а их количеством (и завершением "лишних") будет управлять среда исполннения (интерпретатор(?)) шарпа?

Comment: @avp нет. Точнее, зависит от контекста синхронизации. При вызове из потока UI потребители будут в этом потоке и запускаться. При вызове изх потока без контекста синхронизации потребители будут запускаться в потоках пула.

Comment: @avp спасибо за замечание, кстати.

Comment: Значит, я вообще не понял, как эта штука работает... Что именно делает `await` и где тут создаются-завершаются потоки?

Comment: @avp здесь - потоки вообще не создаются и не завершаются. `await` можно представить как подписку на событие завершения задачи.

Comment: @avp кстати, в C++ тоже ведь хотят async/await включить (только назовут co_await). Пора изучать что оно делает :)

Comment: Да, прибавится проблем с неработающими программами.

Answer (score 5):

## Реализация на C#, Channels

Как [подсказал в комментариях @aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1215825/10105#comment2126284_1215825), начиная с .NET Core 3.0 (и .NET 5) появился ещё один специализированный инструмент: [`Channel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-5.0). Очевидно, он пришёл [под влиянием языка Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2), и описывает, по сути, тот же паттерн Producer/Consumer, но реализованный [более эффективно](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/#relationship-to-the-rest-of-net-core) (за счёт меньшего числа фич).

Класс `Channel<T>` является, по сути, готовой реализацией, из коробки поддерживающей асинхронный интерфейс, отмену через `CancellationToken`, множественных производителей/потребителей и пакетное чтение/запись.

Интерфейс очень похож на интерфейс библиотеки Dataflow, и перевод кода в простых случаях не составит большого труда.

У производителя есть функция для записи одного элемента `WriteAsync`, а если мы хотим сразу записать несколько элементов подряд, может* оказаться лучше использовать `WaitToWriteAsync` и следом синхронный `TryWrite` в цикле. По окончанию добавления элементов нужно использовать `Complete`, чтобы проинформировать потребителей, что больше ждать нечего.

У потребителя есть функция `ReadAsync` для чтения одного элемента, и функция `ReadAllAsync`, которая похожа на `GetConsumingEnumerable` из `BlockingCollection<T>`: она выдаёт последовательность читаемых элементов (но асинхронно), распределяя их по всем потребителям. Если у вас элементы могут приходить большими партиями, вам может* подойти связка `WaitToReadAsync` + цикл с `TryRead`, чтобы не вызывать асинхронную функцию, когда новые задания скорее всего и так присутствуют в канале.

Итак, код производителя.

Простой вариант:

```
async Task ProduceSimple(ChannelWriter<string> writer, int howmuch)
{
    Random r = new();
    int n = 0;
    while (howmuch-- > 0)
    {
        // эмулируем длительную работу по подготовке следующего задания
        // длительность выбираем случайно, чтобы задания приходили в
        // непредсказуемые моменты времени
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
        await writer.WriteAsync($"simple {n++}");
    }
}
```

Вариант с множественной отправкой заданий:

```
async Task ProduceBatched(ChannelWriter<string> writer, int howmuch)
{
    Random r = new();
    int n = 0;
    while (howmuch > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
        // в реальности, задания обычно приходят пачками, так что отправим сразу много
        await writer.WaitToWriteAsync(); // это не нужно, если объём очереди не ограничен
        // случайный размер пачки, вам скорее всего эта логика не будет нужна, т. к. 
        // данные будут приходить группами естественным образом
        var batchSize = Math.Min(r.Next(1, 5), howmuch);
        while (batchSize-- > 0)
        {
            // подготовим задание
            var v = $"batched {n}";
            if (writer.TryWrite(v))
            {
                n++;
                --howmuch;
                if (howmuch <= 0)
                    break;
            }
            // подготовленное, но не отправленное задание нужно сохранить
            // для следующей итерации
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь код потребителя. Базовый вариант совсем простой:

```
async Task ConsumeSimple(ChannelReader<string> reader, int number)
{
    Random r = new();
    await foreach (var v in reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Output(number, v);

        // симулируем длительную обработку результатов клиентом
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(0, 3));
    }
}
```

Если обработка одного задания быстрая, имеет смысл использовать вариант, в котором мы синхронно вычитываем все пришедшие данные раз за разом:

```
async Task ConsumeBatches(ChannelReader<string> reader, int number)
{
    Random r = new();
    while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        // вычитываем всё, что есть в канале, синхронно
        // в этой точке данные могут быть уже уйти другому потребителю,
        // так что цикл может оказаться пустым
        while (reader.TryRead(out var v))
            Output(number, v);

        // симулируем длительную обработку результатов клиентом
        await Task.Delay(1000 * r.Next(1, 3));
    }
}
```

Осталось добавить вызов и запустить:

```
async Task ProduceAll(ChannelWriter<string> writer)
{
    var p1 = ProduceSimple(writer, 20);
    var p2 = ProduceBatched(writer, 25);
    await Task.WhenAll(p1, p2);
    writer.Complete(); // не забываем завершить производителя!
}

Task ConsumeAll(ChannelReader<string> reader)
{
    var c1 = ConsumeSimple(reader, 1);
    var c2 = ConsumeBatches(reader, 2);
    return Task.WhenAll(c1, c2);
}

async Task RunAll()
{
    Channel<string> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    var p = ProduceAll(channel.Writer);
    var c = ConsumeAll(channel.Reader);
    await Task.WhenAll(p, c);
}
```

Вспомогательная функция:

```
void Output(int readerNumber, string v)
{
    // цветной вывод и прочие плюшки
    // мне лень синхронизировать вывод на консоль, хотя конечно это разделяемый ресурс
    if (Console.CursorLeft != 0)
        Console.WriteLine();
    var savedColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)(readerNumber + 8);
    var indent = new string(' ', readerNumber * 4);
    Console.WriteLine($"{indent}[reader #{readerNumber}]: {v}");
    Console.ForegroundColor = savedColor;
}
```

Ну и всё надо упаковать в программу:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args) => await new Program().RunAll();
    // тут всё остальное
```

---

Если вы подружиесь с Channels, возможно, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды, имеет смысл использовать [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/Open-NET-Libraries/Open.ChannelExtensions).

---

*Как именно эффективнее: по одному элементу или в «пакетном» режиме — нельзя сказать заранее. Протестируйте оба варианта под нагрузкой, специфичной именно для вашего приложения. Для варианта «по одному» у вас может быть лишний асинхронный код (как бы не оптимизирован был `ReadAsync`, всё же ему нужно «крутить» состояние стейт-машины). Для варианта «пакетной» обработки вас может настигнуть проблема, когда множество ждущих потребителей (или производителей) одновременно просыпаются и [лишь один из них получает ресурс](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem). Профилируйте!

Спасибо @Pavel Mayorov за полезное обсуждение и примеры из личного опыта.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117458/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--producer-consumer-pattern).