# Ревью класса для очереди команд

Tags: c#, многопоточность, очередь, очередь-задач, инспекция-кода

Мне потребовалась очередь команд, где множество потоков может добавлять команды на выполнение и один поток по очереди их выполняет. Тк я не знаю какие-либо стандартные реализации подобного, то пришлось делать самому. Можете оценить мой класс для этого, тк у меня сомнения на счет его качества, хотя он работает. И если кто-либо даст ссылку на реализации подобного, то тоже будет приятно.

```
public class ConcurrentCommandsQueue<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lockForSyncExecuting;
    private readonly Queue<T> _commandQueue;

    private readonly Action<T> _executeCommand;
    private readonly Action _onStartCommandsExecution;
    private readonly Action<T> _onEndCommandsExecution;

    private volatile bool _isDisposed;
    private volatile bool _isExecuting;
    private volatile Task _taskForAction;

    public bool IsExecuting
    {
        get { return _isExecuting; }
    }

    public ConcurrentCommandsQueue(Action<T> executeCommand) : this(executeCommand, null, null) { }
    public ConcurrentCommandsQueue(Action<T> executeCommand, 
        Action onStartCommandsExecution, Action<T> onEndCommandsExecution)
    {
        _lockForSyncExecuting = new object();
        _commandQueue = new Queue<T>(10);

        _isDisposed = false;
        _isExecuting = false;
        _executeCommand = executeCommand;
        _onStartCommandsExecution = onStartCommandsExecution;
        _onEndCommandsExecution = onEndCommandsExecution;
        _taskForAction = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>().Task;
    }

    private void ExecuteCommands()
    {
        if (_onStartCommandsExecution != null)
            _onStartCommandsExecution();
        T command = default(T);
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_lockForSyncExecuting)
            {
                if (_commandQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    _isExecuting = false;
                    break;
                }
                command = _commandQueue.Dequeue();
            }
            _executeCommand(command);
        }
        if (_onEndCommandsExecution != null)
            _onEndCommandsExecution(command);
    }

    public void AddCommand(T command)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().ToString());

        lock (_lockForSyncExecuting)
        {
            if (_isDisposed)
                return;
            _commandQueue.Enqueue(command);
            if (!_isExecuting)
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                _taskForAction = Task.Run(new Action(ExecuteCommands));
            }
        }
    }
    public void ClearCommandQueue()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().ToString());

        lock (_lockForSyncExecuting)
            _commandQueue.Clear();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        _isDisposed = true;
        lock (_lockForSyncExecuting)
            _commandQueue.Clear();
        if (_taskForAction != null)
            _taskForAction.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это в _ru.codereview.stackexchange_, если бы он был :)

Comment: @i-one Ну его нет, потому сюда написал :-)

Comment: Велосипед? Вот тут есть [решение из фреймворка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428328/10105).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У вас получился код в стиле .NET 1.0, который слегка эволюционировал с приходом лямбд (`Delegate` механически заменён на `Action`) и задач (`new Thread().Start()` механически заменён на `Task.Run()`), но по сути совершенно не изменился: вы TPL с async/await толком не используете, а существование concurrent коллекций вообще упустили из виду.

В .NET 4.5 это всё ненужно в принципе. Если вам нужно выполнение задач строго в одном потоке, то можно просто кидать задачи в однопоточный планировщик задач (task scheduler). Собственно, на этой первой строчке весь код и заканчивается. Если нужно выполнение кода перед всеми операциями и после всех операций, то код перед и после этой строчки и пишется. Отмечу, что при этой однострочной реализации вы ещё имеете бонусом возможность использования токена отмены (cancellation token) и прочих радостей жизни.

---

Рассмотрим пример. Допустим, надо выполнить две очереди задач: в каждой очереди задачи выполняются последовательно, но очереди выполняются параллельно. Создаём два планировщика задач с ограничением параллелизма, затем создаём задачи с указанием нужного нам планировщика.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
    static readonly LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler _schedulerFoo =
        new LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler(1);
    static readonly LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler _schedulerBar =
        new LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler(1);

    static void Main () => new Program().Run().Wait();

    async Task Run ()
    {
        Task queueFoo = RunQueue("Foo", _schedulerFoo,
            Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => (Action)(() => Foo("Foo"))));
        Task queueBar = RunQueue("Bar", _schedulerBar,
            Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => (Action)(() => Foo("Bar"))));
        await Task.WhenAll(queueFoo, queueBar);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    async Task RunQueue (string name, TaskScheduler scheduler,
                         IEnumerable<Action> commands)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: Start");
        await Task.WhenAll(commands.Select(c => RunTask(c, scheduler)));
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: Finish");
    }

    async Task RunTask (Action task, TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(task, CancellationToken.None,
                                    TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
    }

    void Foo (string name)
    {
        int timeout = _rnd.Next(200);
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}:   Start {timeout}");
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}:   Finish {timeout}");
    }
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Foo: Start
Bar: Start
Foo:   Start 165
Bar:   Start 50
Bar:   Finish 50
Bar:   Start 39
Bar:   Finish 39
Bar:   Start 115
Foo:   Finish 165
Foo:   Start 116
Bar:   Finish 115
Bar: Finish
Foo:   Finish 116
Foo:   Start 0
Foo:   Finish 0
Foo: Finish
Done!
```

Хотя в этом примере все задачи и кидаются одновременно, задачи можно добавлять в любой момент. Правда тогда смысл "начала" и "конца" несколько теряется. Если вы объясните, что вы собираетесь с ними делать, тогда можно будет добавить.

Здесь я воспользовался планировщиком `LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler` из примеров на MSDN: [Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework](https://github.com/afedyanin/parallel) (статья с описанием: [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour - #7 - Additional TaskSchedulers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)).

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a task scheduler that ensures a maximum concurrency level while running on top of the ThreadPool.
/// Source: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples
/// Documentation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx
/// License: MS-LPL
/// </summary>
public class LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;

    private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;
    private readonly LinkedList<Task> _tasks = new LinkedList<Task>(); // protected by lock(_tasks)
    private int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0; // protected by lock(_tasks)

    /// <summary>Initializes an instance of the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler class with the specified degree of parallelism.</summary>
    /// <param name="maxDegreeOfParallelism">The maximum degree of parallelism provided by this scheduler.</param>
    public LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler (int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelism));
        _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler.</summary>
    public override sealed int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => _maxDegreeOfParallelism;

    protected override sealed IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks ()
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try {
            Monitor.TryEnter(_tasks, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
                return _tasks.ToArray();
            else
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        finally {
            if (lockTaken)
                Monitor.Exit(_tasks);
        }
    }

    protected override sealed void QueueTask (Task task)
    {
        // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough
        // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another.
        lock (_tasks) {
            _tasks.AddLast(task);
            if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism) {
                ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Informs the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed for this scheduler.</summary>
    private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork ()
    {
        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
            // Note that the current thread is now processing work items.
            // This is necessary to enable inlining of tasks into this thread.
            _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
            try {
                // Process all available items in the queue.
                while (true) {
                    Task item;
                    lock (_tasks) {
                        // When there are no more items to be processed,
                        // note that we're done processing, and get out.
                        if (_tasks.Count == 0) {
                            --_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                            break;
                        }
                        // Get the next item from the queue
                        item = _tasks.First.Value;
                        _tasks.RemoveFirst();
                    }
                    // Execute the task we pulled out of the queue
                    TryExecuteTask(item);
                }
            }
            finally {
                // We're done processing items on the current thread
                _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false;
            }
        }, null);
    }

    protected override sealed bool TryExecuteTaskInline (Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        // If this thread isn't already processing a task, we don't support inlining
        if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems)
            return false;
        // If the task was previously queued, remove it from the queue
        if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
            TryDequeue(task);
        // Try to run the task.
        return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override sealed bool TryDequeue (Task task)
    {
        lock (_tasks)
            return _tasks.Remove(task);
    }
}
```

---

Ещё можно воспользоваться `BlockingCollection<>` с `ConcurrentQueue<>` внутри. По окончанию добавления надо будет не забыть вызвать `CompleteAdding`.

Ещё есть TPL Dataflow. Там параллелизмы и прочие настраиваются без кастомных планировщиков.

Можно ещё Rx добавить в качестве вишенки на торте.

Вариантов море.

Вообще, сейчас ещё **@Vlad** прибежит, расскажет про хитрые мозговыносящие способы решить эту задачу. :)

Comment: ConcurrentQueue не стал использовать, так как я использовал lock. А куда мне тут пихнуть async\await не могу придумать. Пойду почитаю про task scheduler.

Comment: Надо учить TPL :-)

Comment: @Discord: А почему `Monitor.TryEnter`, а не `lock`?

Comment: @Discord: Угу, я бы применил TPL DataFlow, там async-интерфейс из коробки. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431145/10105

Comment: @Discord: «выполнение задач строго в одном потоке» — строго говоря, не вполне так. Любая подзадача может прозрачно уйти в другой поток. Да и саму задачу можно явно запустить в другом потоке через [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (тот, который делает авто-Unwrap).

Comment: @VladD Как вы через `lock` реализуете логику, чтобы при обломе блокировки сразу бросалось исключение, а не блокировался поток? А почему так делается — написано в справке этого метода. / TPL Dataflow — это хорошо, но у него есть минус: его знает гораздо меньше народа, чем банальные async/await. У меня только один лишний аргумент — планировщик. / Ещё любая подзадача может сделать `Process.Start()` и `Environment.Exit()`, ага. :)

Comment: @Discord: Эээ... не увидел логику, да. А зачем `lock`, если при попытке взятия во время `QueueTask` он вылетает? Если ваш код многопоточный, это сомнительная фича. Если он однопоточный, то `lock` не нужен.

Comment: @Discord: `Process.Start` — это грубое вмешательство. А запущенный `Task` может внутри себя применить `await` на другой `Task`, который будет выполняться в другом потоке (или вообще нигде). И скорее всего большая часть времени отработки `Task`'а будет именно так и происходить. Поэтому высказывание «Если вам нужно выполнение задач строго в одном потоке», строго говоря, неверно. Вы можете запустить `Task` на одном TS, он уйдёт в `await` и «перейдёт» в другой поток, вы запустите другой `Task` на этом же TS, и он будет выполняться параллельно первому.

Comment: @VladD Почитайте в MSDN про TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasks, там всё объяснено про блокировки. / Моё утверждение верно про условии, что код не прикасается к многопоточности ни в какой форме. Ладно, положим, код перепрыгнет в другой поток из пула, воспользовавшись async/await. Но, во-первых, почему тогда задачи будут выполняться параллельно? Выполняющий поток будет продолжать висеть на TryExecuteTask, не? Во-вторых, у вас есть предложения, как вернуть выполнение в нужный поток из пула? :)

Comment: @Discord: А, это debugger support only, понял. Тогда вопросов нет.

Comment: @Discord: По поводу TryExecuteTask — не уверен, запутался в исходниках на referencesource. например, что будет если Task горячий? (`Task.Delay(...)`?) [`InnerInvoke`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2867) для этого случая не делает вообще ничего.

Comment: @VlaD Мне тут сейчас потребовалось еще последовательное выполнение с приоритетами. Решил глянуть код этих TaskScheduler, что бы сделать свой с такими условиями. Код там простой, не сложнее моего велосипеда. Может есть такой уже готовый, а то опять сделаю велосипед :-)

Comment: @Nodon: Я не видел готового с приоритетами, так что велосипед вполне подойдёт.

Comment: @VladD В ReprioritizableTaskScheduler приоритетность немного топорная и мне не подходит. Где можно глянуть какой-либо код, использующий приоритеты из ThreadPriority. Интересно посмотреть как там реализовано. Я сейчас сделал по очереди на каждый приоритет с переключением работающей очереди и мне данный вариант не совсем нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [MailboxProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee370357.aspx) - агент для обработки сообщений, который выполняет асинхронные операции. Реализация паттерна "много писателей, один читатель".

Comment: Только это  класс для F# и в C# не рекомендуют его использовать