# Несколько параллельных потоков

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность

Есть класс для обработки пула задач.

```
public class PoolManager
{
    List<Func<Task<string>>> _listFunc { get; set; }
    List<string> _listName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } = false;
    public PoolManager()
    {
        _listFunc = new List<Func<Task<string>>>();
        _listName = new List<string>();
    }

    public async Task<string> StartPool()
    {
        if (!Active)
        {
            Active = true;
            while (Active)
            {
                if (_listFunc.Count != 0)
                {
                    await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var fun = _listFunc[0];
                        RemoveById(0);
                        await fun();

                    });
                }
            }
        }
       return "";
    }

    public void Add(Func<Task<string>> func,string name)
    {
        _listFunc.Add(new Func<Task< string >> (func));
        _listName.Add(name);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Active = false;
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но есть необходимость запускать несколько паралельных таких пулов. запускаю я его так:

```
 if (!VP[0].Active)
 {
      await Task.Run(async () =>
      {
           await VP[0].StartPool();
      });
 }
 else VP[0].Stop();
```

Но таким образом я могу запустить только 1 такой поток. Как можно реализовать одновременный запуск нескольких таких потоков с возможностью в последствии обращаться к ним? И соответственно без блокировки главного потока.

Comment: _обращаться к ним"_ -- для чего вам обращаться к Task'ам?

Comment: @Stack имел ввиду не потерять возможность обращаться к объектам  класса. А то малоли... будут проблемы с обращением или привоением данных полям до окончания потока.

Comment: если Task запущен и читает/сохраняет значения свойств каких-то объектов, то из других Task не надо обращаться если нет lock.

Comment: А почему не [producer/consumer](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105)?

Comment: @VladD по ссылке в примере используется BlockingCollection, я про него и сказал в ответе. см. System.Collections.Concurrent.

Comment: @Stack: Там ещё есть вариант, который использует `Dataflow`, он вроде бы лучше подходит (т. к. async/await).

Comment: @VladD Dataflow видел издалека, в основе используется существующая инфраструктура Task. или нет?

Comment: @Stack: Не совсем. Это собственная инфраструктура, но они выставляют `Task`-интерфейс, потому что это (1) просто, (2) правильно, (3) хорошо ложится на семантику.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создавать список Task'ов не нужно. Просто надо указать AttachedToParent

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /*... */}, 
         TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
}).Wait();
```

Внешний Task дождется завершение всех Task'ов, запущенных в цикле.
Если в основном потоке не надо ждать завершения внешнего Task, то Wait не надо указывать. Но при этом этот Task будет ждать завершение работы остальных, запущенных с AttachedToParent.

Если требуется передавать данные, то надо использовать классы, например, из System.Collections.Concurrent. Пример - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/476958/4).

Comment: А если нужно в процессе добавить новый Таск или удалить определенный? и разве Wait не остановит основной поток приложения?

Comment: _"удалить определенный"_ -- точнее не удалить, а сообщить Task что пора заканчивать. для этого в Task передают CancellationToken.

Comment: _"добавить новый Таск"_ -- можно в любой момент запустить новый Task.

Comment: _"разве Wait не остановит основной поток приложения?"_ -- если в основном потоке не надо ждать завершения Task.Run, то .Wait не надо указывать.

Comment: `Task.Run` использует опцию `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`, так что использовать `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` для присоединения дочерних задач нельзя.

Comment: @PetSerAl я точно помнил, что Run - для внешних Task'ов. но, так у меня в проекте, поэтому получился Task.Run) спасибо. исправил ответ.