# Parallel.For с условием while

Tags: c#, while, tpl

Есть сайт, который я парсю в многопотоке. Главная проблема что я заранее не знаю количество страниц. Поэтому хочу сделать проверку через `while`. Как объединить эти две конструкции? Или может есть альтернатива?

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, count =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(count);
                });
```

Comment: Немного непонятен вопрос. Какую проверку Вы хотите сделать через while?

Comment: Вы можете получить количество страниц заранее, или новые страницы приходят во время разбора текущих?

Comment: Parallel можно заменить на Task c параметром AttachedToParent -- посмотрите пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477430/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/477434#477434)

Comment: А если из разных потоков надо работать с коллекцией, то используйте классы из Concurent -- см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/476958/4)