# C#. Как организовать очередь заданий (потоков)

Tags: c#, очередь-задач

Нужно написать класс, который организует последовательную работу некоторых заданий. Задания по времени могут длится от нескольких минут до часа. Для запуска задания требуется массив с идентификаторами (integer). Так же в этом классе нужен буфер для хранения этих идентификаторов. Опишу принцип работы данного класса:

1) В функцию класса передается массив идентификаторов. В этой функции проверяется, выполняется ли на данным момент задание, если нет - то запускается новое задание. Допустим их нет - значит, запускаем задание #1.

2) Пока выполняется задание #1, классу передается еще один массив, и так как на данный момент есть активное задание, этот массив добавляется в буфер класса.

3) Допустим, задание #1 еще не закончилось, а в функцию передалось еще n-ое количество массивов. Все они тоже должны добавиться в общий буфер.

4) Как только закончится выполнение задания #1, проверяется, есть ли в буфере еще идентификаторы, если есть, запускается задание #2. Этому заданию должны передаться все идентификаторы из буфера, и буфер очищается.

Comment: Судя по всему, вам [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105).

Comment: @VladD "чистые" реализации producer-consumer тут не подойдут. Во-первых, consumer тут должен потреблять элементы не по-одному, а сразу пачками, во-вторых, под consumer поток выделяется не снаружи, а внутри.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну да, поэтому не дубликат, а ссылка :)

Answer (score 1):

Похожую задачу я уже делал, только у меня использовался список запросов. В случае успешного выполнения запроса, у меня выполнялся переход к следующему. Теперь по существу.

1) Создаете список заданий.

```
List<your_task_type> tasks = new List<your_task_type>();
```

2) Добавляете новую задачу в любой момент времени.

```
tasks.Add(new your_task_type);
```

3) В случае успешного выполнения задачи удаляете самый первый элемент списка заданий.

```
if(tasks.FinishedOk)
    task.RemoveAt(0);
```

4) Если очередь задач не пустая, проверяем, активность задачи, и если задача не активна запускаем ее.

```
if(tasks.Count > 0)
{
    if(!tasks[0].IsBusy)
        tasks[0].StartTask();
}
```

Естественно, у вас для всех типов задач должен быть единый интерфейс со свойствами IsBusy, FinishedOk и методом StartTask.

Comment: Лучше вместо обычного `List<T>` использовать какую-нибудь concurrent коллекцию. Тогда не будет проблем с многопоточностью.