# Многопоточное vs асинхронное сетевое программирование на практике

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, асинхронность

Как-то в комментариях `VladD` поделился информацией, что один из его коллег, сетевой программист, перешел от многопоточного к асинхронному сетевому программированию. Хотелось бы на примере конкретной задачи разобраться, насколько асинхронность выиграет у многопоточности.

**Задача:** возьмем один из простых сетевых протоколов - `RFB`. Нам нужно одновременно подключиться к `10 000` серверов с `RFB` на борту, и узнать версию `RFB`.

Как это реализовать многопоточно - я знаю, но как это реализовать асинхронно? И на сколько, в данной задаче, асинхронность выиграет? Сама реализация `RFB` - не нужна, нужен пример выполнения `10 000` одновременных асинхронных запросов.

---

**Протестировал 3 варианта кода:**

- Многопоточный (поменял разбивку списка на несколько - на потокобезопасную очередь, чтобы уровнять шансы)
- Асинхронный
- Асинхронный (паттерн `Throttling`)

**Результаты (проверка `300 000 IP` адресов):**

- Многопоточный: 3 минуты 18 секунд
- Асинхронный: 1 минута 27 секунд
- Асинхронный (паттерн `Throttling`): когда перевалило за 6 минут - закрыл программу и не стал измерять дальше. Скорости можно добиться только использовав в уровне параллелизма - размер всего списка, но тогда теряется смысл самого использования паттерна. Т.е. реализация от `andreycha`, если использовать уровень параллелизма меньше размера списка - работает дольше чем даже многопоточная версия. Возможно это просто `моя` ошибка, либо ошибка `andreycha`.

**Вывод:**

- Стандартная асинхронная реализация работает более чем в 2 раза быстрее чем многопоточная.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37113/discussion-on-question-by-alexis--vs---).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Про асинхронность и ее преимущества [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/491783#491783). Вкратце -- в то время, пока запрос ушел в сеть и не вернулся обратно, мы не блокируем потоки на нашем компьютере. Т.о. 10000 адресов можно вполне обработать, например, несколькими потоками.

Запускать 10000 одновременных запросов это, конечно, перебор. Но запускать, скажем, по полсотни-сотне одновременных запросов -- вполне нормально. Такой шаблон называется троттлингом -- throttling (или в автомобильных терминах -- дросселированием :D). Т.е. пропускаем весь объем заданий по-немногу. Такой подход позволяет несильно загружать канал при отправке запросов и машину при получении и разборе ответов. Примерный код может выглядеть так:

```
public async Task CheckServers()
{
    var servers = new List<string>(10000) { ... };

    const int ConcurrencyLevel = 100;
    
    // запускаем первые 100 запросов
    var tasks = servers.Take(ConcurrencyLevel).Select(GetVersion).ToList();
    int nextIndex = ConcurrencyLevel;

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        // дожидаемся завершения любого запроса
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        
        // удаляем его из списка
        tasks.Remove(completedTask);

        // добавляем новый запрос, если таковые остались
        if (nextIndex < servers.Count)
        {
            tasks.Add(GetVersion(servers[nextIndex++]));
        }

        string rfbVersion = await completedTask;
        // работаем с версией
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetVersion(string server)
{
    // тут асинхронная реализация обращения к серверу по RFB и возвращение версии
}
```

Важный вопрос состоит в правильной асинхронной реализации обращения к серверу по протоколу RFB. Если вы используете библиотеку -- она должна поддерживать асинхронность. Если вы реализуете эту функциональность сами (например, на сокетах) -- значит нужно пользоваться асинхронными функциями сокетов.

**UPD**

Выяснилось, что запросы/ответы у ТС настолько легковесные, что в данном случае троттлинг работает медленнее, чем если отправить сразу все запросы. Однако этот паттерн может быть по-прежнему полезен, когда необходимо ограничить количество исходящих запросов и/или количество обрабатываемых ответов (например, если разбор ответов сильно загружает процессор/требует много памяти).

Comment: Хм, тоесть получается выигрыша не будет? Ресурсов у тестового сервера - навалом. Но толку от 500-1000 одновременных асинхронные обращений к серверам я не вижу. Они и на 20% не загрузят сервер. А переделывать синхронную работу с RFB в асинхронную - пустая трата времени.

Comment: @Alexis а вы попробуйте. И увидите, будет ли выигрыш -- и по нагрузке (сегодня дали хороший сервер, завтра плохой), и по времени выполнения. И нам потом расскажете.

Comment: @andreycha: А почему 10К запросов — перебор? Где bottleneck?

Comment: @VladD я как раз ответ дополнил этим. Узко может быть в сетевых соединениях на отправке и на процессоре/памяти при приеме ответов всем скопом. Это все тестировать, конечно, надо, потому что я не знаю, сколько ресурсов эта штука кушает. Может там и по тысяче нормально пойдет.

Comment: @andreycha: Ну, если есть тулза, которая эти самые 10К коннектов выдерживает, то async/await их точно так же выдержит по идее. Я бы попробовал без throttling'а, а потом с ним. И сравнил. Если уж ресурсов много, и надо все их использовать по максимуму...

Comment: @VladD разумно. Про троттлинг я писал еще по первой версии вопроса, где не было никаких деталей (ни кода, ни уточнений в комментариях).

Comment: @andreycha, проверьте, пожалуйста, свою реализацию паттерна. Результаты тестирования с исходниками проектов добавил в вопрос. Хотелось бы понять - моя это ошибка либо ваша.

Comment: @VladD, добавил тестовые проекты в вопрос.

Comment: @Alexis а какой concurrency level выставляли? Возможно что в вашем случае запросы и ответы настолько легковесны, что при данном сочетании количества запросов и имеющихся ресурсов троттлинг не имеет смысла, как и предполагал VladD.

Comment: @andreycha, пробовал разные варианты, начиная от 100 и заканчивая половиной списка (150 000).

Comment: @Alexis понятно. Ну значит в вашем случае троттлинг действительно не нужен. Спасибо за опубликованные результаты.

Comment: @Alexis возможно у вас остался код тестовых вариантов (в вопросе ссылок больше нет). Вопрос интересный, сам бы поковырял примеры...  Вы не могли бы выложить код заново? Возможно выслать мне на почту?

Comment: @nikita, та ссылка умерла, вот новая: https://www.sendspace.com/file/mxw469

Comment: Что-то реализация throttle какая-то многословная... Можно же и короче сделать, аж двумя способами.

Comment: Вариант первый: асинхронный семафор. Все задачи запускаются одновременно, но каждая сначала ждет на семафоре.

Comment: Вариант второй: очередь и набор исполнителей. Исполнители стартуют одновременно и по-очереди обрабатывают последовательность заданий.