# Поиск фразы по библиотеке текстов

Tags: c#

Есть много текстов, штук 500, каждый размером с книгу. Как оптимально организовать поиск точной фразы, вводимой пользователем, по этим текстам с помощью c#? Скорость важна, тексты всегда одни и те же.

UPD. А если я разобью все тексты на предложения, можно будет как то ускорить поиск с помощью БД, например?

Comment: Загрузить тексты в БД, использовать полнотекстовый поиск.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ради всего 500 текстов не рационально заводить полноценную БД. Это несет лишние издержки на обслуживание.

Comment: Если фраза должна состоять точно из слов текстов, то можно сделать индекс слов с их смещениями в тексте и построить поиск, использующий этот индекс.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это быстрее будет чем без БД?

Comment: @avp фразы может и не быть в текстах и можно ссылку что за индекс со смещениями?

Comment: Использование базы данных для данных, которые помещаются в память, не ускорит, а скорее всего и замедлит поиск. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: Ссылку на то, что такое индекс? Наверное можно найти в гугле, лучше почитать что-нибудь про реализацию баз данных (если найдете). Вообще, у вас индекс это структура данных, где слово это ключ, а адресуемые ими данные это смещения от начала текста, где данное слово встречается. Наверное для такой задачи с каждым словом (ключем в индексе) стоит хранить и количество мест, где оно встречается. Это позволит при анализе по словам фразы выбрать наиболее редко встречающееся слово и читать только те места текста, где оно есть. Соответственно, меньше текста сравнивать с другими словами фразы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый быстрый поиск информации производится с помощью [поискового индекса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81). Конечно, чтобы его можно было использовать, сперва его нужно составить.

Если в вашем проекте уже используется какая-либо СУБД, поддерживающая [полнотекстовый поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), то логично использовать её. В противном случае, следует поискать какой-либо поисковый движок.

Одним из наиболее известных поисковых движков является [Lucene](https://lucenenet.apache.org/). Устанавливать проще всего с помощью [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/). [Пример](https://csharpdreams.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/simple-search-engine-in-c-with-lucene-net/) использования в .NET.
Можно посмотреть на [hOOt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224722/hOOt-full-text-search-engine).

---

Всегда ли это будет быстрее, чем тупой перебор текстовых файлов? Нет. Однако, даже если количество и размер файлов относительно невелики и они могут целиком уместиться в ОЗУ, то всё равно использование индекса может оказаться быстрее: ведь в большинстве случаев загрузка файлов вообще не понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить тексты в потокобезопасную очередь (`ConcurrentQueue` например), поднять 500 потоков, и в них проверять тексты из очереди, где каждый текст проверяется в своем потоке. Так же есть разные варианты с асинхронными задачами, циклами `Parallel.For`, `Linq.ForEach` и т.д.

Приводить примеры кода без конкретики бессмысленно.

Comment: Зачем 500 потоков?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не обязательно потоков, можно асинхронных задач. Вот к примеру: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать Lucene,есть порт на .net [Lucenenet](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet). Индекс сделать заранее, и из приложения искать по нему нужный документ. Вот ещё ссылка [Introducing-Lucene-Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net)