# Полнотекстовый поиск на сайте Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, полнотекстовый-поиск

В веб-приложении, которое пишу на asp.net mvc 5, нужно реализовать полнотекстовый поиск. У меня в базе есть таблица *инструкции*, в которой есть другие таблицы - *категория*, *теги*, *шаги*. В таблице *шаги* есть таблица *блоки*. В поисковой строке я должен вводить какую-то строку и результатом вывода должны быть инструкции. Строка эта может быть в категории, в блоках, где угодно. Подскажите, что для этого нужно использовать. И если не сложно, ссылку на какой-нибудь пример.

Заранее спасибо за отзывчивость и внимание )

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? Большинство имеют поддержку полнотекстового поиска. Просто включаете её и используете. Например, в SqlServer компонент [Full-text Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search).

Comment: Если используемая СУБД не имеет встроенного полнотекстового поиска, то можно использовать какой-либо fulltext search engine. Например, движок Lucene. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532675/184217).