# Умные алгоритмы поиска в базе данных (asp.net)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net, поиск

Есть сущность товара. Один товар может иметь много названий (на разных языках). Название может быть например такое: `Шланг садовый economic трехслойный 1/2" 50м`. Как найти такой товар по строке `Шланг сад` я знаю, а вот как найти товар по строкам `Садовый шланг`, `Шланги`, `50 метров шланг`, `трехслойный шланг` и подобных я не знаю.

Что пришло в голову:

- гуглить на серверной стороне по своему же сайту и выводить список страниц с совпадениями.
- связать каждый товар с коллекцией тегов. В каждом поисковом запросе разбивать запрос на теги. Искать товары с максимальным количеством совпадений связанных тегов с тегами из поискового запроса.

Есть ли готовые библиотеки для умного поиска в базе данных? Или какие-то продвинутые подходы для поиска информации на сайте? Сайт на asp.net mvc

Comment: ищи по вхождению слова шланг оно везде есть чет не понятна проблема

Comment: Во-первых, гуглить по своему сайту хорошая идея, многие так делают :) Во-вторых, вот вам ключевая фраза для погуглить: движки полнотекстового поиска

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532675/184217

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться полнотекстовым поиском на пример *elasticsearch* (Отдельная база данных. Если будешь искать на стороне back-end производительности не будет(

Comment: Эм, а если elasticsearch не back-end, то что это?

Comment: база данных) back-end я имел ввиду на стороне бизнес логики

Answer (score 1):

я на сайте editpress.ru(asp.net mvc,ms sql server 2012) пользуюсь full-text search поднятой на стороне ms sql server. https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms142547(v=sql.105).aspx . Также я пробовал на стороне asp.net серверного кода использовать lucene.net, но в итоге вцелом full-text search неплох.