# c# Поиск дубликатов строк в очень больших файлах

Tags: c#

стоит задача выполнить поиск дубликатов в текстовом файле размером около 50 Гб.
строки длинной от 8 до 32 символов.
Для начала просто найти дубликаты и показать их на экране.
Как решить подобную задачу в приемлемый срок(до 48 часов) с использованием c#?
пытался пробегать и сравнивать построчно, но это не для таких объёмов.
Логика подсказывает что нужно файл разделить на M частей по N строк.
считывать в память части и там их сравнивать. Но что-то мне подсказывает это вариант не сильно быстрее.

Но может существует какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: Это одноразовая задача или подобный поиск нужно будет осуществлять часто?

Comment: Это у вас noSQL БД. Регулярные выражения помогут.

Comment: Полагаю можно на лету бить файл на кусочки и считывать его параллельно. Дубли можно попробывать поискать по хэшу. Но первый вопрос был правильный - это надо делать на постоянке или разово?

Comment: Выгрузить эти строки в любую нормальную БД и задача сведётся к тривиальной.

Comment: Эта задача регулярная.

Comment: Хотя подозреваю что для 50GB и sqlite хватит и формальна задача будет решена на C# :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532675/184217

Comment: Строки отсортированы? Если нет, то можно отсортировать их методом сортировки слиянием больших файлов. После сортировки поиск дубликатов - дело тривиальное.

Comment: строки не отсортированные.

Comment: Строки похожие друг на друга или произвольные?

Comment: Следующая партия 50 гигов будет содержать в основном те же строки или каждая партия файлов в основном с новыми строками?

Comment: Даже не так. Следующая партия файлов как то зависит от предыдущей? Например, если вы ваши 50 гигов в базу запишете, это поможет вам с поиском дубликатов в следующем 50 гиговом файле?

Comment: Если бд для вас не вариант, то смотрите мой коммент про сортировку.

Comment: строки произвольные. новый файл не будет зависеть от предыдущего. Присматриваюсь к варианту с sqllite. Вопрос в производительности этого метода.

Comment: Если каждый файл независимый, то тогда вам каждый раз придется создавать новую бд, что не имеет особого смысла в плане производительности. Я бы посоветовал сортировку слиянием для больших файлов, информации об этом алгоритме валом. Один минус - вам понадобятся как минимум еще 50 гигов места на диске и скорость алгоритма сильно зависит он производительности диска.

Comment: я ранее не встречался с этими алгоритмом сейчас почитал про него и не совсем понял. в нём идёт речь про сравнение двух файлов. то есть мне придётся сделать копию исходного файла. Но есть также одно Но на мой взгляд. если число повторений будет очень мало, то массив в памяти должен разрастись до больших размеров, так?

Comment: Смысл алгоритма в том, чтобы разбить файл на мелкие файлы, мелкие файлы отсортировать при записи, и потом мелкие файлы объединять в большой так, чтобы на выходе большой файл получился сортированный.

Comment: Если убрать дубликаты (A,B,C,B,A -> A,B,C), то сколько всего строк ожидается? А то может быть достаточно будет в Dictionary или HashSet всё загрузить.

Comment: дубликатов ожидается не более 0,5%