# Поиск строк на совпадение в текстовых файлах C#

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, другу понадобился софт, который удаленно, на его сервере ищет из всех содержащихся там текстовых файлов совпадение по заданному слову. Я написал класс отвечающий за TCP соединение и вот тут вопрос по классу, который будет искать. В принципе все работает, даже системные ресурсы не так сильно жрет (за исключением процессора до 20%), но все же скорость поиска меня не устаревает, хочется побыстрее.
Вот код и вопрос, как можно улучшить, ускорить его работу

```
foreach (string item in dirWork)
{
    foreach (string item2 in SafeEnumerateFiles(item))
    {
        using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(item2), 1024 * 1024)))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = await _reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(ItemSearch))
                {
                    name.Add($"{Path.GetFileName(item2)}");
                    result.Add($"{line}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`dirWork` содержит коллекцию папок лежащие на разных дисках. `SafeEnumerateFiles(item)` метод возвращает полную коллекцию всех файлов в папке и подпапках.

Comment: Если есть сеть, значит узкое место там. Показанный код выглядит нормально.

Comment: @aepot поиск производится на TCP сервере, т.е в самом приложении, найденные строки отправляются клиенту, а так же имя файла

Comment: Интерполяции строк лишние, привОдите строки к строкам.

Comment: @aepot да, спасибо, забыл убрать, т.е скорость тут более не выжать?

Comment: `StringComparison.Ordinal` в помощь.

Comment: Возможно, следует убрать асинхронность. Или же вместо `File.OpenRead` использовать `new FileStream` с параметром `bool async` = true.

Comment: Если искать нужно часто и много, то стоит посмотреть на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532675/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [по-секрету](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218926/12888024).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужна скорость, то я бы вот что попробовал

1. Убрал бы асинхронность. Асинхронность делает приложение более отзывачивым, но конкретная операция может стать медленней из за построения конечногго автомата и переключений контекста. Но это чисто догадка, я не проверял её правдивость.
2. Увеличил бы буфер. Один мегабайт таки это маловато. Я бы сделал магабайт 10-100 на поток
3. Обрабатывал бы файлы параллельно. При большои буфере в одном потоке когда файл считыватся, проц простаивает и когда данные обрабатываются - простаивает жесткий диск.

Вот пример

```
private IEnumerable<(string filename, string line)> GetFilieredLines(string file, string pattern)
{
    using(var reader = new StreamReader( new BufferedStream( File.OpenRead(file), 10*1024*1024) ))
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if(line.Contains(pattern)) yield return (file, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Как вызывать

```
var folder = @"D:\.....";
var results = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(x=>GetFilieredLines(x, "public class"))
    .Dump();
```

Вывод

[image: ...]

Comment: Ругается на это, инфы про дамп не могу найти `.Dump();`

Comment: так уберите `.Dump()` из кода, это метод LinqPad - проги, которую я использовал, чтобы запустить скритп на C#

Comment: @tym32167 Если вы сравните размер строк до вызова Contains: if (line.Length >= pattern.Length && line.Contains(pattern)) - это может ускорить сравнение в 5-10 раз для тех случаев, когда искомая строка длиннее итерируемой. В противном случае замедление будет ~10-15% (больше похоже на погрешность, т.к. разница в миллисекунды на 10_000_000 строк). Ускорение связано с тем, что внутри метода Contains выбрасывается перехватываемое исключение ArgumentOutOfRangeException ровно на той-же самой проверке.

Comment: @Blackmeser там проверка на StartIndex, который всегда 0. К тому же подобные оптимизации сильно зависят от характера данных в файлах и паттерна.

Comment: Там проверка: ``if (count < 0 || startIndex > this.Length - count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException`` которая true, когда длина входящей строки больше внутренней, т.к. выполняется условие ``0 > line.length - pattern.length``

Comment: @Blackmeser не совсем, ведь в качестве count там [передается](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2340) `this.Length`, то есть выражение `startIndex > this.Length - count` становится `startIndex > this.Length - this.Length`, то есть в случае, что я выше описал, это будет `0>0`, что никогда не является верным. То есть вы можете смело писать `if (string.Empty.Contains("long string")) {}` и никаких исключений выкинуто не будет.

Comment: @tym32167 точно, перепутал строку, но почему тогда такое падение производительности если всё время вызывать Contains?...

Comment: @Blackmeser это надо замерять. Просто предположу, что дело доходит до [неуправляемого вызова](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,851), что само по себе требует некоторого времени.

Comment: @tym32167 может быть один раз, для инициализации, но не для каждой же строки... Хотя тема довольно интересная, узнать сколько времени занимает такой вызов.