# Массовое сравнение строк, поиск пересечений, каким инструментом воспользоваться?

Tags: c#, mysql, алгоритм, .net

Есть некое множество слов, пусть это будет 100 000 слов.

Есть некое количество текстов, пусть будет 150 000 текстов, пусть среднее количество слов в каждом тексте будет 50.

Есть программа которая ищет в цикле каждое слово из первого множества, сейчас это все в массивах и просто сравнивается между собой, на что уходит очень много времени.

Есть ли такие системы которые могут выполнить такие проверки с большим количеством параллельных потоков или еще как то?

Какие идеи пока что посетили меня.
Положить первое множество в таблицу MySQL, и навесить ключ на поле с этим множеством.

Далее положить во временную таблицу InMemory все слова из текстов и потом соеденить их через `INNER JOIN`. Но у нас в каждом тексте может быть несколько совпадений с первым множеством и как при этом отделить одно от другого мне не совсем понятно.

Может можно как то использовать Elasticsearch, Redis и тому подобные системы?

Comment: См. алгоритм Ахо-Корасик, за один проход ищет вхождение сразу многих подстрок. Вы не его ищете?

Comment: @Harry как этот алгоритм относится к большому количеству итераций сравнения строк?

Comment: В данном случае проблема не в поиске строк а в большом количестве этих поисков

Comment: Множество слов постоянно? Если да, то отсортировать его, а далее использовать бинарный поиск - он чрезвычайно быстр. / Или, может, тексты постоянны и отсортированы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532675/184217

Comment: При поиске поочередно N слов в текстах длиной M - O(NM), при поиске Ахо-Корасик O(M). Еще раз - одним проходом ищется одновременно вхождение любого из множества слов.