# Как для обычной задачи задать параметр TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning?

Tags: c#, .net

Пример от `andreycha` паттерна `throttling`:

```
public async Task CheckServers()
{
    var servers = new List<string>(10000) { ... };

    const int ConcurrencyLevel = 100;

    // запускаем первые 100 запросов
    var tasks = servers.Take(ConcurrencyLevel).Select(GetVersion).ToList();
    int nextIndex = ConcurrencyLevel;

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        // дожидаемся завершения любого запроса
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        // удаляем его из списка
        tasks.Remove(completedTask);

        // добавляем новый запрос, если таковые остались
        if (nextIndex < servers.Count)
        {
            tasks.Add(GetVersion(servers[nextIndex++]));
        }

        string rfbVersion = await completedTask;
        // работаем с версией
    }
}
```

Как в подобной реализации красиво задать параметр `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` задачам? Это вообще возможно без использования `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: Никак. Нет. Это не нужно.

Comment: @Athari, да ну, нужно это, ибо увеличивает на ~20-30% производительность софта если использовать Task.Factory.StartNew. Если бы от этого небыло толку, я бы не спрашивал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите. Давайте разделим `Task`'и и другие асинхронные функции на те, которые ограничены процессором (то есть, занимают фиксированный поток длительное время), и остальные.

Для первых функций `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` имеет смысл, т. к. мы не хотим надолго блокировать поток из пула потоков. Но такие функции обычно предоставляются в виде синхронных функций, которые мы запускаем через `Task.Run`. Так что можно, при желании, запустить и через `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Для остальных асинхронных функций нету понятия «поток, в котором функция бежит», и большую часть времени Task не бежит *нигде*, просто ожидая окончания `await`. Для таких функций `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` лишено смысла, и задать его сложно (если и можно вообще). Но в этом случае эта опция и не нужна.

Comment: Работаю над увеличением скорости, это грубо говоря продолжение этого моего вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-vs-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: В моем случае, переделав паттерн на Task.Factory.StartNew - удалось увеличить производительность, т.к. криптография протокола дает нагрузку в основном на процессор, спасибо за разъяснение. Я просто хотел узнать, есть ли способ более красиво и просто оформить код.

Comment: @Alexis: Вроде бы другого способа нет, по крайней мере я не знаю.