# Уточнение по асинхронным сокетам и паттерну throttling

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

В [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-vs-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5/) теме тс написал, что запустив все задачи разом (подключение к  300 000 разным IP адресам) - эффективнее, чем использовать ограничивающий паттерн throttling.

**Вопрос:** если мы сразу запустим все задачи, без троттлинга - не забьются ли у нас все доступные TCP порты? Ведь, если я правильно понимаю, каждый сокет занимает один свободный порт, всего у нас 65535 портов, а IP адресов у нас 300 000. Это чревато большими потерями.

Comment: все зависит от задач

Comment: @Grundy, простое подключение и ничего более. Грубо говоря сканер портов.

Comment: Хм. А почему бы не просто проверить?

Answer (score 4):

Если задача быстрая, то порт будет занят на *очень* короткое время. И 65к портов хватит, чтобы "одновременно" проверить все 300к адресов (потому что проверяются они на самом деле не одновременно). Плюс в библиотечной реализации возможны оптимизации, когда для нескольких соединений используется один порт, как это сделано, например, в `HttpClient`. Но чем больше времени будет занимать задача, тем больше это скажется на общей производительности и занятых портах.

Но да, проще всего написать код, запустить, посмотреть занятые порты и поиграться со временем выполнения задачи.