# Можно ли использовать один локальный TCP порт для нескольких сокетов?

Tags: c++, windows, сеть

Есть клиентское приложение. За приложением закреплен только один локальный TCP порт.

Задача: создать несколько сокетов на одном локальном порту и одновременно подключиться с них к нескольким разным серверам в интернете.

Это возможно? Если да - как это сделать? Какие опции поставить в setsockopt?

Comment: если подключаться по очереди, то все возможно.

Comment: @KoVadim, одновременно имелось ввиду. Дополню вопрос.

Comment: @Abyx, это уже ограничения заказчика. Приложению разрешено использовать лишь один локальный TCP порт. Понимаю что изврат, но что делать...

Comment: В этом случае нужна прокся. А через нее можно ганять любой траффик

Comment: @KoVadim, следовательно - никак не получится? Про прокси понял.

Comment: ну почему нельзя. Можно конечно, только нужно добавить несколько айпишников. И с каждого с них уже делать подключение.

Comment: @KoVadim, а если не задействовать дополнительные IP адреса на сетевом интерфейсе? Меня вот этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698007/261345 немного смущает, если в HttpClient-е это реализовано, значит можно без дополнительных IP адресов обойтись.

Comment: http подключения короткие (в идеале) и можно переиспользовать сокет.  Но можно биндить серверный сокет с нескольких приложений (в линуксе точно можно) и ядро будет разбрасывать подключения по кругу.

Comment: Задал отдельный вопрос, дабы прояснить ситуацию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698547/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-httpclient-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd

Comment: функция `bind()` Вам в помощь