# Как именно в HttpClient реализована возможность нескольких соединений через один порт?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть

Вопрос основан на [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698007/261345) ответе.

Хотелось бы понять, как именно реализована данная оптимизация в HttpClient?

Comment: Тот вопрос случаем не вы задавали? Если так, то может остановитесь на одном юзере? :) Модераторы могут помочь смержить двух пользователей.

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто. 
Подключение идентифицируется парой портов. Таким образом один и тот же порт может подключиться ко сколь угодно многим портам.

1.2.3.4:1234 -> 5.6.7.8:80
1.2.3.4:1234 -> 9.0.1.3:80
и т.п.

Используется один и тот же клиентский порт.

Тоже самое, что сервер принимает все подключение на одном и том же порту.

1.2.3.4:80 <- 5.6.7.8:1234
1.2.3.4:80 <- 9.0.1.2:5678