# Отправка пакетов по UDP (UDPclient) C#

Tags: c#, udp

Здравствуйте, пишу клиент-сервер основываясь на UDP протоколе, все сделал дебажа на локал хосте, но когда решил затестить приложение уже в локальной сети то столкнулся с иной проблемой, а именно - пакеты иногда теряются, даже если я выключу инет и оставлю только wi-fy. В чем может быть проблема, на локал хосте все работает максимально правильно. Не знаю что делать в такой ситуации, прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: UDP подразумевает, что проверка ошибок и исправление либо не нужны, либо должны исполняться в приложении. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP Этот протокол легко позволяет терять пакеты по причинам, описанными по ссылке выше.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

UDP-пакеты имеют право теряться, всё в порядке. Это ожидаемое поведение. Если вам нужна гарантированная доставка, используйте TCP.

Или вы можете отправлять на сервер подтверждение приёма, и при отсутствии такого подтверждения повторять передачу. Но такой велосипед будет по сути повторять то, что делает TCP внутри.

Comment: я решил переделать логику под TCP, теперь у меня начались очень странные проблемы... а именно при отправке файлов у меня идет такая последовательность
а) клиент(принимает файл):
1. Send (пустое сообщение, что бы соинхрнизироваться)
2. Receive - получаю инфу о файле
Цикл (пока не придет уведомление что конец файла)
3. Receive - 1 пакет 
4. Send (пустое сообщение) для уведомления о том, что я закончил преобразование пакета
конец цикла (после цикла, сохраняю файл)

Сервер (отправитель) (тоже самое но инвертирую)
Сейчас допишу

Comment: б Сервер:
1. Receive - получим пустое сообщение о готовности 
2. Send - инфа о файле 
цикл для всех пакетов 
3. Send - отправляем 1 пакет
4. Receive - Жду подтвержения (пустое сообщение) 
конец цикла
5. Send - конец отправки фала (в цикле клиента проверется, я пояснил перед объявлением цикла)

Comment: Собственно, это работало отлично на локал хосте на протоколе UDP, теперь на TCP возникает очень странная ситуация, что даже при такой синхронизации, где-то либо клиент, либо сервер могут застыть (чаще сервер) и все... Реши проблему странным образом (а может не решил, но ошибок не было) установил в начале каждой итерации сон для потока на 15мс

Comment: Но в другом месте, где вызываю этот метод на прием, все равно... Может возникнуть такой дедлок, и оба приложения, что клиент, что сервер застынут.

Comment: Повторю вопрос, что за бред? почему на UDP (127,0,0,1) все работало отлично, а теперь с TCP, все работает ужасно, если можно так выразится(тоже Local host), я уже не знаю какие мне костыли пихать...,

Comment: Даже в некоторых моментах, при тех же условиях, может зависнуть выполнение

Comment: @simplygood: О TCP это уже следующий вопрос. И по идее мне кажется, что не стоит делать такой сложный обмен сообщениями (но это не тема данного вопроса).

Answer (score -1):

> теперь на TCP возникает очень странная ситуация, что даже при такой синхронизации, где-то либо клиент, либо сервер могут застыть (чаще сервер) и все...

Возможно потому что TCP использует блокирующие сокеты для связи. Для того чтобы подключение, прием, отправка сообщений не останавливали поток, либо выделяйте операцию в отдельном потоке (для простоты можно использовать класс BackGroundWorker), либо используйте асинхронные методы BeginAccept, BeginReceive, BeginSend, BeginConnect.

Очень хорошо разница между синхронными и асинхронными запросами описана тут 
[Нужен async/await или не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Или вот вам подробный пример TCP клиент-сервера https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI

Если все же решите дальше исследовать вопрос с UDP, то для предотвращения потери пакетов обычно пишут обертку над UPD обеспечивающую подтверждение каждого доставленного пакета. Если для какого либо пакета не пришел ответ о доставке, его посылают заново. Для отправки больших пакетов их "вручную" фрагментируют на части, каждый из которых подписывается.

Организовать очередь пакетов на отправку можно по разному, например циклическим массивом.