# Туманности и мои пробелы в знаниях с async\await и Task'ами в целом

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность, task, context

Здравствуйте, я захотел опробовать такую вкусняшку C# как `async/await` и написал тестовую программу:

```
class MySynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post");
        base.Post(d, state);
    }
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send");
        base.Send(d, state);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchronizationContext());
        var browsers = GetBrowsers();
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        Console.WriteLine(browsers.Result);
    }
    static async Task<string> GetBrowsers()
    {
        var res = string.Empty;
        var bd = await GetFromFS();
        res += bd;               // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
        var net = await GetFromNet();
        res += " and " + net;   // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
        var cpu = await Task.Run<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(200); return "edge"; });
        res += " and " + cpu;   // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
        return res;
    }
    static async Task<string> GetFromFS()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\bd.txt"))
        {
            var res = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            // тут могла быть операция с UI
            return res + " and firefox";
        }
    }
    static async Task<string> GetFromNet()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        // тут могла быть операция с UI
        return "chrome";
    }

}
```

Я ожидал, что после каждого `await'а` мой контекст будет восстанавливаться (ведь будь это приложение с UI, то надо же получать доступ к контролам), а значит, что после каждого `await'а` в консоль будет выводится "Post", но каково было мое удивление когда вывелся только 2 раза. Отсюда вопрос:

1. почему контекст привязывается не всегда?

Теперь к `async/await`: как я понимаю, начиная с `var browsers = GetBrowsers();` вызов будет проводится по стеку вниз до первого таска (в данном случае `sr.ReadToEndAsync();`, а может и ниже), и управление сразу перейдет обратно в метод `Main()`, не дожидаясь завершения этого таска; остальная часть `async`-методов будет выполняться после выполнения данного таска и так далее, из чего возникает следующий вопрос:

2. кто ждет тот самый первый таск (затем следующие, когда до них дойдет
   очередь после `await'а`), изменяет его состояние на
   `RanToCompletion`? Думаю, было бы глупо думать, что для ожидания
   выделяется поток из пула потоков, да?

Третий вопрос стоит на стыке тасков и пула потоков. Продолжение после `await`, как я понимаю, выполняется в пуле потоков (там ему передается контекст), но...

3. что засовывает часть кода после `await` в пул потоков и когда (когда
   таск завершился или когда создался?)?

Заранее спасибо за прояснение ситуации

Comment: Тем не менее, попробуйте этот же код в гуевом приложении. Что-то изменится?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, изменится, но это порождает еще больше вопросов, чем ответов, так как переключением контекста занимается async\await. Грубо говоря, если я буду знать ответ на свой первый вопрос - скорее всего я буду знать почему в UI все немного иначе, так что вопрос остается открытым

Comment: Возможно, эта статья немного прояснит как реализуется асинхронность если отбросить весь синтаксический сахар async\await и посмотреть на это всё в чистом TPL.
http://bit.ly/2G269sp

Answer (score 3):

1. Дело в том, что выполнение метода `Post()` в вашем контексте вы делегируете базовому методу. А [базовый метод](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/16705ba05372139e.html) ставит делегат на выполнение *в пуле потоков*. В случае с UI такого не происходит, потому что, например, WinForms контекст полностью [переопределяет](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/de633159d3cb47c3.html) методы. Вставим логирование контекста и текущего потока в ваш код:

   ```
   class MySynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
   {
       public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Post, thread id = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
           base.Post(d, state);
       }

       public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Send, thread id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
           base.Send(d, state);
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return "My";
       }
   }

   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchronizationContext());
           var browsers = GetBrowsers();
           Console.WriteLine("start");
           Console.WriteLine(browsers.Result);
       }

       static async Task<string> GetBrowsers()
       {
           LogCurrentContext("GetBrowsers prologue");
           var res = string.Empty;
           var bd = await GetFromFS();
           LogCurrentContext("GetBrowsers after GetFromFS");
           res += bd;               // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
           var net = await GetFromNet();
           LogCurrentContext("GetBrowsers after GetFromNet");
           res += " and " + net;   // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
           var cpu = await Task.Run<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(200); return "edge"; });
           LogCurrentContext("GetBrowsers after Task.Run");
           res += " and " + cpu;   // <-тут могла быть операция с UI
           return res;
       }

       private static void LogCurrentContext(string message)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"{message}: {(SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "default")} context, thread id = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
       }

       static async Task<string> GetFromFS()
       {
           LogCurrentContext("GetFromFS prologue");
           using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\GetEventsMarkets.sql"))
           {
               var res = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
               LogCurrentContext("GetFromFS after ReadToEndAsync");
               // тут могла быть операция с UI
               return res + " and firefox";
           }
       }

       static async Task<string> GetFromNet()
       {
           LogCurrentContext("GetFromNet prologue");
           await Task.Delay(200);
           // тут могла быть операция с UI
           LogCurrentContext("GetFromNet after Task.Delay");
           return "chrome";
       }
   }
   ```

   Чаще всего я получал подобный результат:

   ```
   GetBrowsers prologue: My context, thread id = 1
   GetFromFS prologue: My context, thread id = 1
   Post, thread id = 1
   GetFromFS after ReadToEndAsync: default context, thread id = 3
   start
   Post, thread id = 3
   GetBrowsers after GetFromFS: default context, thread id = 3
   GetFromNet prologue: default context, thread id = 3
   GetFromNet after Task.Delay: default context, thread id = 4
   GetBrowsers after GetFromNet: default context, thread id = 4
   GetBrowsers after Task.Run: default context, thread id = 4
   ```

   Здесь нам интересны две вещи.

   - В кастомном контексте вызываются только прологи методов `GetBrowsers()` и `GetFromFS()`. После того, как выполняется строка `await sr.ReadToEndAsync()`, продолжение метода `GetFromFS()` постится в кастомный контекст. Это первый вызов `Post()`. Далее метод `GetFromFS()` завершается и продолжение метода `GetBrowsers()` снова постится в кастомный контекст. Это второй вызов `Post()`. Однако поскольку кастомный контекст просто запускает код в пуле потоков, эти продолжения работают уже *в контексте пула потоков*. Именно поэтому мы больше не видим вызовов кастомного контекста.
   - Метод `GetFromFS()` начал исполняться в потоке с id=1. Однако само продолжение при этом выполнялось в потоке с id=3 по причине, описанной выше. Продолжение после вызова `GetFromFS()` было вызвано в этом же потоке (`Post, thread id = 3`).
2. "Самый первый таск", как и любой другой, ждет специальный *IO поток* (т.н. IO completion port, IOCP). Но такие потоки ждут очень большое количество завершений, в т.ч. и тасков, поэтому говорить о "один таск -- один ждущий поток" не приходится. Нырнуть вглубь и почитать подробнее можно в [статье на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/).
3. Продолжение async метода выполняется в *захваченном* контексте. Если такого контекста нет (например, при вызове с `ConfigureAwait(false)`) -- продолжение выполняется в контексте пула потоков. Вызов продолжение в соответствующем контексте выполняется компилятором -- он генерирует соответствующий код с вызовом `Post()`. Компилятор разбирает async метод на составляющие (пролог+продолжения) и генерирует из них стейт-машину с переходами. Очень рекомендую посмотреть [это выступление](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA) (или хотя бы [слайды](http://andreycha.info/files/dotnext-msk-14/async-await_avoiding_common_mistakes-slides.pptx)), а также ознакомиться с [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/106). После этого фразы вроде "async/await занимается переключением контекста" должны пропасть из вашего обихода.

Как резюме: вы получили смущающие результаты потому, что ваша реализация контекста, строго говоря, некорректна. По сути она аналогична контексту пула потоков, который используется для консольных приложений и в котором исполняются все продолжения, если не был обнаружен другой контекст.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46521/discussion-on-answer-by-andreycha--------async-awa).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. почему контекст привязывается не всегда?

Проблема вашего контекста - в том, что он не умеет восстанавливать себя. Если вы пишите свой контекст - то вы сами должны позаботиться чтобы все продолжения запускались в нем же.

> 2. кто ждет тот самый первый таск

Если асинхронность правильная - то "самый первый" `Task`, как и все последующие, создается при помощи механизма `TaskCompletionSource`.

Например, так (код привожу только для примера, в реальности надо еще исключения обрабатывать):

```
Task<int> VeryFirstTask() {
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
   Action handler = null;

   handler = () => {
     tcs.SetResult(42);
     SomeEvent -= handler;
   };

   SomeEvent += handler;
   return tcs.Task;
}
```

Не обязательно используются события - но идея одна и та же. Где-то сохраняется `TaskCompletionSource`, у которого в нужный момент вызывается `SetResult`/`SetException`/`SetCanceled`.

> 3. что засовывает часть кода после await в пул потоков и когда (когда таск завершился или когда создался?)?

Напрямую его туда засовывает контекст синхронизации.

Опосредовано в этом участвует так же такая структура данных как `TaskAwaiter` (она хранит захваченный контекст синхронизации).