# Блокируется UI при использовании async-await C#

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть форма с `button` и `Label`. При нажатии на кнопку выполняется метод `button1_Click`:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Список IP адресов.
        List<string> ListIP = new List<string>();

        // Метод getListPC(timeout) возвращает список ip адресов.
        ListIP = getListPC(50);

        // WMI-Класс, который позволяет получать информацию о ПК по IP:
        // Имя, процессор, материнская плата, список установленных программ и др.
        WMI current = new WMI();
        foreach (string el in ListIP)
        {
            label3.Text = el;
            // CheckАccess(IP) - метод класса WMI, позволяет проверить доступность ПК.
            await current.CheckАccess(el);
        }
    }
```

Код класса WMI

```
class WMI
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private ConnectionOptions Connection { get; set; } = new ConnectionOptions();

    public Task<bool> CheckАccess(string ComputerName)
    {
        try
        {

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + ComputerName + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementScope scope =
                new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ComputerName + "\\root\\CIMV2", Connection);
            scope.Connect();
            searcher.Scope = scope;
            searcher.Get();
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            logger.Trace(e.StackTrace + " " + e.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Во время подключения к ПК `scope.Connect()` в экземпляре класса `WMI` происходит блокировка UI. Почему это происходит? Разве перебор цикла `foreach` не должен быть продолжен без ожидания завершения метода `CheckАccess`?

Comment: scope.Connect(); ... return Task.FromResult(true); - никакой асинхронности (читай ухода в другой поток кроме UI потока), а просто костыль для впихивания в TPL

Comment: Ближайший костыль - обернуть вызов CheckАccess или внутри самого CheckАccess (по необходимости) в Task.Run(). По нормальному - переписать доступ к ManagementScope  в асихнронный вид (если он это поддерживает).

Comment: Перебор цикла ждёт завершения каждого элемента. Вы об этом явно говорите, когда пишите `await`. Хотя блокирует вас не это =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучшим вариантом будет использование `Task.Run`, поскольку вы тогда явно укажете кодом, что хотите выполнять данный метод на потоке из ThreadPool, и что контекст UI вам в нем не интересен, и что это обертка над синхронным методом. Это если у классов `ManagementObjectSearcher` и `ManagementScope` нет асинхронных методов.

```
await Task.Run(()=>current.CheckАccess(el));
```

Comment: Совет про `ConfigureAwait` и `Task.Delay` -- плохой. Там в цикле идет обращение к UI, а значит контекст должен сохраняться. Уберите первую часть ответа, не путайте людей.

Comment: @andreycha Не совсем согласен с тем, что контекст сохранится - ConfigureAwait(false) по идее заставит запланировать задачу в пуле. Ну а сам хак грязный.

Comment: Убрал хак из ответа:)

Comment: @vitidev я не говорю, что контекст сохранится. Я говорю, что он должен сохраняться, потому что после асинхронной операции идет обращение к UI (которое должно быть в UI-контексте).

Comment: Я проглядел обращение к Label, тогда да, тот хак работать не будет.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin Ну еще есть Task.Yield(), в паре с которым хак был бы работоспособным, хотя хак сам по себе не имеет права на жизнь

Answer (score 6):

Тот факт, что метод `CheckАccess` возвращает `Task` и вы рядом с его вызовом написали `await`, не делает его асинхронным. Почитайте [краткое изложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/491783#491783) того, что делает `async/await`, посмотрите [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA).

Проблема в том, что у вас весь метод `CheckАccess` выполняется синхронно. Варианта решения проблемы, как уже подсказали, два:

1. Переписать вызов WMI в асинхронный вид, если это возможно.
2. Обернуть вызов `CheckАccess` или вызов WMI самого `CheckАccess` в `Task.Run()`.