# Async, await и что я делаю не так?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Не очень силён в async/await, не могу понять, что мне студия советует сделать.

```
public class ManagerService
{
    public ManagerService()
    {
        Task.Run(Observe);
    }

    private async Task Observe()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Observe");
        } 
    }
}
```

"В данном асинхронном методе отсутствуют операторы await, поэтому метод будет выполняться синхронно. Воспользуйтесь оператором await для ожидания неблокирующих вызовов API или оператором await Task.Run(...) для выполнения связанных с ЦП заданий в фоновом потоке."

await в моём понимание мне не нужен, так как я ждать чего либо не собираюсь, просто запускаю процесс в фоновом потоке. Использовать "await Task.Run(...)" не получается (возможно не правильно это пытаюсь сделать), и не понимаю, что это мне даст.

Вообщем вопрос в том, что я теряю, если оставляю как есть?

Comment: `await в моём понимание мне не нужен `

Как и ключевое слово `async`, тогда. Зачем оно там?

Comment: А действительно, у меня просто в какой то момент без него не получалось, а с ним вышло, но сейчас попробовал убрать и вроде как работает. Короче, рано полез.

Comment: «связанных с ЦП» — не самый лучший перевод для «CPU-bound».

Comment: Tсли необходимо ждать то вызовите после .Run() .Wait() или GetAwaiter

Comment: @VladD а как стоило поступить в данном случае?

Comment: @agimgal: Ну, я не про код, я про перевод с английского на русский в тексте исключения.

Comment: @VladD, Это студия сама, просто она на русском.

Comment: @agimgal: Я знаю, вот на их перевод и ворчу, не на вас :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

async/await в методе `Observe` вам вроде бы действительно не нужен. Поскольку в нем не используется ключевое слово `await`, то Студия говорит вам о том, что и `async Task` не нужен. Должно получиться так:

```
private void Observe()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Observe");
    } 
}
```

Если вы решите оставить ключевое слово `async`, то теряете маленькие крохи на производительности, поскольку для таких методов компилятор генерирует специальный код, вызов которого стоит дороже, чем вызов обычного метода.

Однако в методе есть один недостаток: при вызове `Thread.Sleep()` поток будет блокироваться и простаивать без работы. Это не очень хорошо (а иногда и вообще критично). Здесь нам как раз может помочь асинхронный вариант ожидания: `Task.Delay`. И теперь async/await снова имеет смысл:

```
private async Task ObserveAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Debug.WriteLine("Observe");
    } 
}
```

Подробнее о том, как работает async/await и почему блокировать потоки плохо, можно почитать [в другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/491783#491783) или посмотреть [доклад](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA).

Другой момент: завершение метода. Если у вас есть бесконечный цикл, то нужно предусмотреть выход из него. И если логика метода такого не предполагает, то нужно использовать некую команду извне. Для этого рекомендуется использовать `CancellationToken` (при этом его можно использовать как в синхронном, так и в асинхронном варианте):

```
// не забудьте по окончании работы вызвать Dispose()
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

public ManagerService()
{
    Task.Run(Observe);
}

private void Observe()
{
    while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Observe");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Наверное, лучше не `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, а `var cancelled = token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);`.