# Асинхронное выполнение метода при запуске окна

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Есть код:

```
public async Task Async() {
  var T = new List < string > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    T.Add(i.ToString());
  }
  tt.ItemsSource = T;
}

private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  await Async();
}
```

Все выполняется, но он все равно блокирует окна, и с ним нельзя взаимодействовать, пока не выполнится метод.

Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Ключевое слово async не делает никакой магии не заставляет метод выполняться асинхронно. [Почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/106), [посмотрите](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA).

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task Async()
{
     tt.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() =>
     {
          var T = new List<string>();
          for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
          {
               T.Add(i.ToString());
          }
          return T;
     });
}
```

Comment: все равно при запуске окна не могу немогуне чего делать пока listbox незаполнится

Comment: Это нормально, так после запуска Task поток освобождается и захватывается когда Task возвращает результат. То о чем вы говорите другая задача

Comment: Вы не правильно используете ключевые слова, окно зависает не от того что **Task** запущен, а от того что вы делаете это синхронно.
Выше дал ответ.

Comment: @Birdy: Странно, а что не правильно в этом ответе? Там же `Task.Run`, вроде всё в порядке.

Comment: @VladD, Если посмотреть что будет на выходе, то непонятно зачем так сделано, и все естественно зависнет
`private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  await Async();
}


public async Task Async()
{
     tt.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() =>
     {
          var T = new List<string>();
          for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
          {
               T.Add(i.ToString());
          }
          return T;
     });
}`
Зачем ожидается то что не возвращает результат?

Comment: @Birdy: У меня окно не зависает, что я делаю не так? Для примера заменил 10000 на 1000000, во время работы `Task.Run` окно можно вполне таскать по экрану. А вот присвоение `ItemsSource` и создание огромного количества item'ов, да, подтормаживает, но ТС спрашивает не об этом. Попробуйте для тестов добавить `Thread.Sleep` на каждой итерации.

Comment: @Birdy - не зависает. модификатор async в т.ч. говорит компилятору, что данный метод нужно специальным образом скомпилировать. Побочным эффектом специальной компиляции и является тот факт, что вместо `Task` можно возвращать `void`, а вместо `Task<T>` -- `T`.

Answer (score 1):

**Async** делит ваш метод надвое, и работает так:

- исполняет весь код, предшествующий ожиданию *await*
- завершает исходный метод (выходит)
- Ждет, пока [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) не сообщит ему, что *awaited* код завершен
- исполняет весь код, следующий за *await*

Проблема в том, что в `Async()` нет *await*, поэтому все работает синхронно.

Если ваш метод async не зависит от других методов async (выполняет работу с CPU), вы должны использовать`Task.Run`:

```
public async Task Async()
{
    tt.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var T = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
           T.Add(i.ToString());
      }
      return T;
    });
}
```

[async/await how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063520/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-method-in-c)

[async/await intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

[как работает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

[Очень подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-async-await-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd/491783#491783)

**UPDATE**

Если проблема в том, что при запуске окна с ним нельзя взаимодействовать, пока listbox не заполнится, a для его загрузки требуется некоторое время и пользователю там нечего делать пока listbox пуст, то покажите вращающийся курсор мыши и отключите все кнопки.

Comment: Нельзя делать присваивание `tt.ItemsSource = T;` в другом потоке

Comment: такая же проблема как в ответе ниже

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, вы правы. Ошибка копирования - alexsandr-ter правильно написал

Comment: @Санитариум - Покажите вращающийся курсор мыши и отключите все кнопки

Comment: @PavelMayorov, он исправил.

Comment: скурсором понятно ну  а если это будет долго идти я хочу например что то другое сделать с окном например переместить его.Я его даже переместить не могу оно польностью заблокировано

Comment: @Санитариум - курсор мыши. Или вы можете создать всплывающее сообщение с надписью «Двигаем спутники на позицию»

Comment: @Санитариум - я написал решение -  `tt.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() =>`... Позволит вам перемещать окно

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **Dispatcher**, если не доступны методы Invoke и другие, допишите **Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher**.необходимый_метод

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => // или InvokeAsync
{
    // Ваш код здесь
}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Так же можно запустить поток, в этом же диспетчере.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (ThreadStart) delegate
{
    /*Ваш код здесь*/ 
});
```

Думаю это то что вам нужно:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)); // имитируем долгую операцию
    });
    Title = "Выполнено!";
}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Если все же не понятно:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    tt.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)); // имитируем долгую операцию
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            result.Add($"Item ID: {i}");
        }
        return result;
    });
    Title = "Выполнено!";
}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Не забудьте сделать метод **Window_Loaded** синхронным.