# Зачем вызывать асинхронный вариант метода в методе контроллера?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net-core, асинхронность, asp.net-core-2

Читая код одного из разработчиков нашей команды, наткнулся на такие строки:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser([FromRoute] int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ...

    return Ok(user);
}
```

Вижу такой код не в первые, а именно вызов в контроллере ASP.NET Core Web API асинхронный вариант некого метода (в данном случаи `SingleOrDefault`)

```
var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

**Зачем это делается, разве все методы контроллера так и так не вызываются в отдельном потоке?**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/196257

Comment: Вы путаете асинхронность и многопоточность. Синхронный вариант блокирует поток. Асинхронный поток не блокирует. Потому асинхронный предпочтительней - так как пока сервер ждет ответа от БД, он может переиспользовать поток для других запросов в асинхронном случае.

Comment: Цель как раз не использовать поток в то время, пока ожидается ответ от базы

Comment: @tym32167, теперь встает другой вопрос: в каких случаях `SingleOrDefault` предпочтительнее чем `SingleOrDefaultAsync`? Потому что мне теперь кажется, что смысл использования `SingleOrDefault` полностью теряется при существовании варианта Async, разве что для каких-то определенных задач, но вопрос, какие это задачи?

Comment: не всякий `SingleOrDefault` лезет в БД. например, для коллекции в памяти нет никакого смысла использовать асинхронный вариант. Также не все БД поддерживаются асинхронную работу (например, насколько я помню, EF (какая то предыдущая версия) для sql compact не поддерживает асинхронные операции)

Comment: `Цель как раз не использовать поток в то время, пока ожидается ответ от базы` — почему? Поток всё равно простаивает, к тому же это недешёвый по памяти ресурс. Асинхронный вызов функции сохраняет текущий контекст выполнения и выполняет прыжок в обработчик следующего запроса. Как только асинхронная функция завершит работу, поток быстро вернётся к сохранённому контексту и продолжит прерванную работу.