# Что лучше использовать - Thread или asyns

Tags: c#

Недавно я узнал о существовании async/await.Я хочу спросить совета если я заменю создание нового потока для ожиданий подключений и нового потока для каждого нового пользователя на async/await сможет ли мой сервер не останавливая основного потока программы принимать новых пользователей и опять же через async/await создавать для них class-ы и выполнять код для каждого в отдельном потоке

Comment: Если все правильно сделаете, то именно так и будет. Отдельные потоки будут браться из пула когда и если это будет необходимо.

Comment: @rdorn вот по этому примеру ориентируюсь https://gist.github.com/jamesmanning/2622054

Comment: неплохой пример как основа, только постарайтесь до конца разобраться что там зачем и почему, тогда сможете расширить его под все ваши нужды. Ну и здесь про `async/await` уже много чего понаписали с подробностями и нюансами, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491632/198316) например.

Comment: Главное надо понимать, что асинхронность != многопоточность. Тут на сайте куча ответов, поясняющих разницу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен async/await или не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-async-await-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd)