# Синхронный вызов vs await Task.Run() для CPU-bound операций .Net

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, асинхронность

Многие рекомендуют, как например [здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/dodopizzadev/blog/435666/), использовать Task.Run() для Cpu-bound операций.

В статье по ссылке написано, что Task.Run() стоит использовать  если:

- мы используем WinForms и хотим оставить наш UI поток отзывчивым
- мы хотим распараллелить задачи
- мы используем CPU-bound операции

Насчет CPU-bound операций у меня непонятка. Согласно рекоммендациям нужно писать так:

```
    public async Task Foo()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => PerformLongCpuOperation());
    }

    public void PerformLongCpuOperation()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            i = i * 32;
        }
    }`
```

Но что мы выиграем? Мы просто выносим операцию в фоновый поток. Да, вызывающий поток вернется в пул потоков, но у нас все так же будет один поток выполнять работу, плюс мы тратим ресурсы на переключение контекста. Не проще ли вызвать метод синхронно? Я не имею ввиду случаи с WinForms и WPF, где вызывающим потоком может быть UI поток.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен async/await или не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-async-await-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ни разу не дубликат. В том вопросе обсуждались произвольные операции, а тут речь идёт только о CPU-bound

Answer (score 2):

Эта рекомендация даётся для потоков UI, то есть именно для тех случаев WinForms и WPF, которые вы откинули.

Если работа в UI-потоке не предполагается, то проще и правда вызывать синхронно.

Answer (score 2):

> Согласно рекоммендациям нужно писать так:

```
public async Task Foo()
{
   await Task.Run(() => PerformLongCpuOperation());
}
```

Нет. Вовсе нет.

Во-первых, тут создаётся лишний конечный автомат. Правильнее писать так:

```
public Task Foo()
{
    return Task.Run(() => PerformLongCpuOperation());
}
```

К Студии есть немало дополнений, которые указывают на эту ошибку и предлагают изменить код.

Во-вторых, такой метод-враппер бессмысленен и не нужен.

[Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) - серия статей от Stephen Cleary.

Кратко: если метод `PerformLongCpuOperation` по сути своей синхронный - то он должен существовать сам по себе, без лишних обёрток. Когда нужно запустить его в отдельном потоке, `Task.Run` пишется по месту.

Если он по сути своей асинхронный, то это совсем другое дело.

Comment: О, спасибо за ссылку. Еще не читал. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Читал эту серию статей, но сбило то, что есть и другие статьи, которые несколько искажают написанное. Хотел бы уточнить ещё вот что... если заменить await Task.Run() на return Task.Run() то: вернётся ли вызывающий поток в пул потоков или он будет заблокирован; будет ли вызывающий поток ожидать выполнения фонового потока или пойдёт дальше?

Comment: @maxhanin `await` на `return` менять с убиранием `async` можно и нужно, но только если: 1) у вас единственный `await` в методе, 2) после `await` нет кода. Убирание `await` таким образом никак не повлияет на `Task`, созданный в `Task.Run`, но избавит метод от машины состояний, и не будет генерить еще один awaitable `Task`, а просто пробросит дочерний `Task` в `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Если время выполнения метода меньше, чем время запуска нового потока ~30мс, и больше быть не может, смысла запускать его через `Task` мало. С другой стороны, сколько у вас пусков такого метода?

Если тяжелая однотипная операция повторяется в течение работы программы, то можно просто запустить долгоживущий поток, повесить там бесконечный цикл, ждущий получения команды на выполнение или/и аргументов и выполняющий нужную операцию немедленно ([Producer-Consumer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern)). В результате получится, что расходов на асинхронность практически нет, потому что не запускаем `Task`, а используем один долгоживущий, а обмен данными можно реализовать например через `BlockingCollection`, или/и коллбэк `IProgress`.

По поводу CPU-bound и I/O-bound еще написано [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Конкретно для вашего примера можно выполняться синхронно.

Здесь нет красной кнопки "уничтожить всех человеков", или убойного шаблона программирования, который будет ответом на ваш вопрос и будет учитывать все случаи жизни. Пробуйсте несколько вариантов, профилируйте, замеряйте производительность. Отталкивайтесь от задачи и прямого ее решения, затем прямое решение постепенно превращайте в более элегантную, расширяемую и удобную реализацию.