# PLINQ или Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, plinq

Есть задачка: на входе один или несколько EXCEL файлов. Я преобразую все ячейки в текст и просто записываю все в новый текстовый файл, который я так же создаю программно.

Есть однопоточная версия данного приложения: консольное приложение с библиотекой NPOI для работы с Excel файлами. Проблема в том, что когда программа обрабатывает много, очень много файлов, то работает очень долго. Поэтому хочу ускорить её и сделать многопоточную версию. Подскажите как лучше реализовать многопоточность.

До этого никогда не сталкивался с многопоточностью. Когда начал искать на предмет возможных решений моей проблемы, то нашел PLINQ и Parallel.ForEach. Подскажите, что лучше использовать.

Comment: А почему бы вам не попробовать оба варианта и не рассказать нам, что лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Пытаясь читать или писать много файлов в разных потоках, много вы не выиграете, поскольку все в конечном счете упрется в диск. Поэтому я бы посоветовал следующую схему:

- Чтение и запись файла с помощью асинхронных операций (смотрите в
  сторону асинхронных методов типа `ReadAsync()` и `async/await`). Если библиотека для чтения Excel файлов не поддерживает асинхронную работу, значит читайте многопоточно, но нужно экспериментировать и проверять, при каком количестве потоков вы получите наилучшую скорость.
- Преобразование ячеек в текст можно делать многопоточно
  (`Parallel.ForEach` или PLINQ).

`Parallel.ForEach` и PLINQ скорее всего дадут примерно одинаковые результаты (однако ничто не мешает измерить оба варианта). Что выбирать -- зависит в первую очередь от того, какая функциональность нужна:

- если методы обработки элементов не зависят друг от друга, порядок обработки не важен, выбирайте `Parallel.ForEach`
- если важен порядок обработки элементов, выбирайте PLINQ (см.
  [`AsOrdered()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered(v=vs.100).aspx))
- если вам нужен стрим процессинг (ленивая обработка), выбирайте PLINQ
- если нужно обрабатывать две коллекции вместе, выбирайте PLINQ
- если нужен thread-local state, выбирайте `Parallel.ForEach` (он имеет встроенную поддержку)
- если нужна отмена, выбирайте `Parallel.ForEach` (см. [`ParallelLoopState.Stop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`ParallelLoopState.Break()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break(v=vs.110).aspx))

Подробнее можно узнать в документе ["When Should I Use Parallel.ForEach? When Should I Use PLINQ?"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf).

---

Также при схеме "чтение-трансформация-запись" вам может пригодиться [producer/consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern), таких пар у вас будет две (чтение-трансформация и трансформация запись). Одно из преимуществ заключается в том, что если части конвейера работают с разной скоростью, то есть возможность регулировать производительность отдельных частей, тем самым оптимизируя производительность (и по скорости, и по потреблению памяти) всего конвейера.

Answer (score 0):

Многопоточность - это разделение одной большой задачи на несколько маленьких работающих параллельно, не поможет вам `PLINQ`, вы можете модифицировать свою программу сделав ее многопоточной, для этого создайте пул потоков и вынесите парсинг Excel в отдельный поток, в итоге вы получите прибавку к скорости пропорционально количествe процессоров.

В парсинге Excel стандартный `Open XML SDK` будет побыстрее `NPOI`