# Проблема с Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

имеется фрагмент кода

```
int readen = 1;
int i = 0;
while (readen > 0)
{
    if (msList.Count >= 20)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        msList.Add(new MemoryStream());
        gzsList.Add(i, new GZipStream(msList.Last(), CompressionMode.Compress));
        readen = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        compressTasks.Add(new Task(() => { (gzsList[i] as GZipStream).Write(buffer, 0, readen); }));
        i++;
        compressTasks.Last().Start();
    }
}
```

проблема в том что в строке `compressTasks.Add(new Task(() => { (gzsList[i] as GZipStream).Write(buffer, 0, readen); }));`происходят непонятные вещи: при выполнении условия не происходит засыпание треда, а выполнение переходит на эту  строку и соответственно вываливается исключение, причем зависящий от типа коллекции `gzslist`(для ``` List``System.InvalidOperationException ```, `Dictionary` `KeyNotFoundException`, `Hashtable` `NullReferenceException`. Если убрать условие, то все равно вываливаются исключения, но при разной величине коллекции(зависит от запуска(от 20 до 50)

Comment: А зачем вы `Task` используете как потоки? Почему не современный async/await?

Comment: И ещё, непонятно, почему добавление `Task`'а в коллекцию должно приводить к засыпанию потока.

Comment: А ещё вы расшарили между `Task`'ами **переменную** `i`, это бомба замедленного действия (подумайте, почему).

Comment: мне кажется, или буфер там тоже общий?

Comment: Не добавление должно приводить К засыпанию потока, а после добавления если в коллекции слишком много элементов( тобишь consumer работает медленее producer)  необходимо дождаться появления свободного места в коллекции. И можно подробнее почему плохо шарить int между тасками? Он же передается по значению и по идее не должно быть проблем

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Не, лямбда захватывает `i` по ссылке. Так что у вас разделяемая переменная с понятными последствиями.

Comment: @VladD не знал что лямбда захватывает по ссылке, в будущем пригодится, сейчас же сделал нормальную имплементацию Producer-Consumer, попутно выясним что нельзя сжимать куски 1го файла несколькими `GZipStream`

Comment: @ArtemiyBorodin: Возможно, вам пригодится это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105