# Как уведомить одну задачу через другую в .NET?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

здравствуйте, есть цель: сделать определенное действие в одном потоке по некоторому "событию" из другого... допустим, один в бесконечном цикле отправляет в сеть один пакет, а при возникновении "события" в другом потоке, начинает посылать в сеть другой пакет...

```
class Notifier {

int atomic_flag = 0;

static void sending() {
    while(1) {
        if(!atomic_flag)
           /*одно действие*/
        else
           /*другое действие*/
    }
}

static void observable() {
     /*...*/
     //происходит "событие"
     atomic_flag=1;    
     /*...*/
}    

static void Main()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(sending);
    Task task2 = new Task(observable);

    task1.Start();
    task2.Start();
}
}
```

возможно ли сделать то же самое как следует, а не используя переменную с side-эффектом?

Answer (score 2):

Как мне кажется, то задача содержит противоречие: нельзя "не использовать переменную с side-эффектом" изменить поведение, когда одна из функций крутися в бесконечном цикле.

В этом случае нужно некоторое разделяемое поведение, через которое эта функция сможет получить информацию о том, какую логику использовать.

Один вариант решения - это шаренная потокобезопасная переменная. Это может быть еще одна таска, это может быть любая другая переменная, позволяющая читать и писать себя атомарно: например, volatile переменная ссылочного типа.

Вот один из вариантов на основе таски:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Notifier
{

    private static Task<bool> taskThatMeansSomething = Task.FromResult(true);

    static async Task SendingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            bool flag = await taskThatMeansSomething;
            if (flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Flag is true. Doing one thing");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Flag is false. Doing one stuff");
            }

            await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    static async Task Observable(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool result = false;
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Changing the flag to {result}");
            taskThatMeansSomething = Task.FromResult(result);

            result = !result;
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Task sendingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            async () => await SendingAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token), 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        Task observeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            async () => await Observable(cancellationTokenSource.Token),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 5 seconds...");
        Task.WaitAll(sendingTask, observeTask);
        Console.WriteLine("Done! Press \"Enter\" to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Waiting 5 seconds...
Flag is true. Doing one thing
Changing the flag to False
Done! Press "Enter" to exit.
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
Changing the flag to True
Flag is true. Doing one thing
Changing the flag to False
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
Changing the flag to True
Flag is true. Doing one thing
Flag is true. Doing one thing
Changing the flag to False
Flag is false. Doing one stuff
```

Ну и там несколько моментов:

1. Таски нужно запускать через `TaskFactory.StartNew` и указывать, что они долгие (поскольку они долгие)
2. Можно и даже желательно, прикрутить graceful cancellation через `CancellationTokenSource` и `CancellationToken`.
3. Разумно использовать стандартную для C# идиому именования.
4. Разумно сделать long running методы возвращающими `Task`.

Вместо шаренной переменной `taskThatMeansSomething` можно подумать в сторону того же TPL Dataflow, когда в зависимости от изменения входных данных будет запускаться разные блоки, которые отвечают за отправку данных в одном или в другом режиме.

Вот тогда можно будет полноценно уйти от разделяемого состояния в сторону более actor-based parallelism-а. Если интересно, то я могу набросать этот вариант тоже.

Comment: набросайте пожалуйста, если не сложно... другое дело, что с async/await у меня глухарь еще тот, знаю только что на основе fsm реализовано, и все)

Comment: Там я писал про TPL Dataflow. Это совсем другой зверь. Но я набросаю.

Comment: хм, я вот думаю: а чем шаренная таска лучше обычного булевого флага?

Comment: Тем что она потокобезопасна. Булевый флаг помеченный volatile будет работать тоже. Без volatile, компилятор (C# и JIT) могут наоптимизячить такого, что поведение будет совершенно некорректным.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то для таких целей используется [ManuaResetEventSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: хм, ну это блокирует поток на ожидание, а нужно чтобы он работал и в том, и в другом случае

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, честно говоря, написал так:

```
async Task T1(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        /*одно действие*/
    }
}

async Task T2(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        /*другое действие*/
    }
}

async Task Coordinator()
{
    using (var cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var t1 = T1(cts1.Token);
        /*...*/
        //происходит "событие"
        cts1.Cancel();
        await t1;
    }

    using (var cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var t2 = T2(cts2.Token);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Проблема в том, что вы пользуетесь не тасками, а потоками. Нет, формально у вас есть таск, но фактически вы работаете с ними как будто это потоки. поэтому вы и думаете о том, как бы запустить в том же таске другое задание, хотя это в принципе не нужно.

Таск не должен думать, в каком потоке он находится, а для отмены таска идиоматичным является `CancellationToken`. Ну и делать два различных дела в одном таске как бы неправильно.

Comment: плохо у меня с async/await... разбираться надо

Comment: @xperious: Обязательно разберитесь, это ключевая техника в асинхронных задачах.

Comment: в плюсах такого нету к сожалению, по крайней мере на уровне языка, вот только в шарпе столкнулся первый раз, хотя давно уже слышал про это

Comment: @xperious: Может быть, вам ещё пригодится [producer/consumer](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105).

Comment: благодарствую...