# Правильное общение Task между собой

Tags: c#, .net, task

Допустим, один Task непрерывно читает данные, а другой Task должен их обрабатывать по мере их получения с некоторой периодичностью.

Какие существуют способы передачи данных в существующий Task обработки данных?

Самое банальное, это общение поле класса. Это правильно?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, поля класса для такого использовать - неправильно!

Задача - это элемент ФП (функционального программирования). Она должна получать входные параметры через замыкание - а выдавать результат через возвращаемое значение. Изменяемое поле класса не является ни тем, ни другим.

Нарушение этого принципа приводит к тому, что вам теперь нужно беспокоиться о синхронизации разных потоков. А синхронизация потоков в многопроцессорной среде - это не то, чему можно научиться по-быстрому.

---

Ваша задача является классической задачей Producer-Consumer (поставщик-потребитель). Более подробно решения этой задачи можно увидеть тут: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/178779).

Если коротко - то вам надо либо использовать блокирующую очередь, [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) - либо [BufferBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx) из библиотеки TPL Dataflow для асинхронной обработки.

Также вместо задачи-обработчика можно создать ActionBlock и подцепить его к BufferBlock.

Также есть вариант не передавать данные, а создавать новую задачу-обработчик на каждую порцию прочитанных данных, используя однопоточный планировщик задач для обеспечения последовательности обработки. Но внутри такого планировщика все так же будет Producer-Consumer, просто передавать он будет задачи а не данные.

Comment: Стоит еще сказать, что таски для этого не преднозначены.

Comment: @Fynivx вообще говоря, таски предназначены для любых процессов, у которых надо проверять результат.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, очевидно, что не для всех. Во-вторых, я имел ввиду, что таски - абстракция более высокого уровня, и используя их вот так, в лоб, можно огрести кучу проблем. В .NET есть более специфичные примитивы для данной проблемы - System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.

Comment: @Fynivx а что, Dataflow не через таски работает? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov через таски, но сам таск нужен для исполнения однйо задачи. Задать вход -> получить выход. Dataflow же используя таски и в том числе и BlockinngCollection позволяет повысить уровень абстракции для решаемых задач.

Comment: @PavelMayorov через таски, но его разработчики наверняка в курсе, что таски в .Net - это просто удобная абстракция два выполнения асинхронных операций, и ничего больше, и что в работе с ними есть куча вопросов, о которых должен думать разработчик. Готова ли ваша реализация обработки потоков данных к тому, например, что таск запустится на удаленной машине? А ведь такое может произойти.