# реализация доступа к данным из нескольких потоков

Tags: c#

Добрый день!

c# .net 3.5

Есть несколько потоков, которые находят ошибки независимо друг от друга, мне нужно реализовать такую вещь - чтобы эти потоки складывали данные куданибудь и потом другим потоком я их оттуда извлекал и как то обрабатывал. Что посоветуете?

Comment: [Producer/consumer](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105)?

Comment: Используйте метод Syncronize потоков...

Answer (score -1):

Два потока складывают найденые ошибки в какую нибудь ConcurrentCollections, а трети поток извлекает их отуда.

Ваша задача это задача постовшика и потребителя [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), но он появился только в 4.0, а вам нужен 3.5.

Для net 3.5 могу посоветовать использовать [Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary)