# Создание блокирующей очереди с шаблоном Producer-Consumer , switch-context

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня задание реализовать шаблон Producer-Consumer так, что-бы получилась блокирующая очередь. Producer добавляет в очередь, а Consumer из нее забирает. Если очередь пуста то потоки ждут до появления новых данных.

И что-то у меня получается совсем не внятное:

```
public class ProducerConsumer<E> {

    private Queue<E> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private boolean permit = true;
    private final static Object lock = new Object();

    public void producer(E data) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!permit) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            queue.add(data);
            switchPermit(true);
        }
    }

    public E consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!permit || queue.size() == 0) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            switchPermit(false); //и тут проблема он разбудит продюсера
            return queue.poll(); //до того как сделает poll
        }

    }

    private void switchPermit(boolean position) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            permit = position;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста написать такую очередь. Что-то я совсем запутался...

Comment: Вот это, возможно, пригодится: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105. Версию на C# можно легко адаптировать.

Comment: @VladD да я уже это видел, но тут с адаптацией туго, я в C# и helloworld в жизни не писал... Может кто из умных людей откликнится...

Comment: А зачем вам понадобился `permit`?

Comment: @VladD для того что-бы как -то включать и выключать wait()

Comment: Используйте пакет Concurrent и его функционал блокировок, уберите синхронизацию и задержку потоков, используйте ReentrantReadWriteLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваша реализация шаблона больше всего походит на [TransferQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TransferQueue.html), т.е. когда Consumer ждет пока Producer пришлет данные в очередь, а Producer ждет пока Consumer считает данные из очереди.

Т.о. критерием ожидания является наличие данных в очереди, а искусственный флаг permit не нужен.

```
class ProducerConsumer<E>
{
    private Queue<E> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public synchronized void producer(E data) throws InterruptedException
    {
        queue.add(data);
        this.notify();

        // wait for consumer
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            this.wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized E consumer() throws InterruptedException
    {
        while(queue.isEmpty())
        {
            this.wait();
        }
        this.notify();
        return queue.poll();
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что notify() все еще вызывается до poll(), но это не проблема, т.к. на самом деле другой поток получит управление только по выходу текущего их монитора синхронизации.

Также, обратите внимание на то, что в вашем коде lock статический, т.е. синхронизация будет идти по всем экземплярам и не исключено, что notify разбудит поток не этого, а другого экземпляра.