# Web Api - организация общей очереди для всех пользовательских сессий

Tags: c#, tpl

Коллеги, я изучаю TPL и хотел бы выполнить следующую задачу =>

{

На стороне Web Api организовать общую очередь задач от пользователя (например 
  запись данных в базу данных) и последующую ее обработку в пяти потоках по 
  одной задаче.
  При этом надо знать сколько задач ждут в очереди и имеются ли задачи в работе.

return Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть и имеются для этого средства в PTL 
  DataFlow?

}

Comment: Обычно между фигурными скобками код. Забыли добавить?

Comment: Ну, чем не подойдёт producer/consumer? Например, вот эта реализация: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431145/10105

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Думаю это то что надо.