# Вызвать событие при добавлении элемента в ПУСТУЮ потокобезопасную коллекцию

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Множество потоков добавляют элементы в ConcurrentQueue,  а один другой поток извлекать их и обрабатывать.

Вот функция обработки элементов:

```
public async Task PacketSender()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (PacketQueueForSend.TryDequeue(out Packet packet))
        {
            await packet.ClientTcp.Send(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Добавление в эту очередь я пытался сделать так:

```
private async void PacketAddToQueue(Packet packet, ClientTcp receiver)
{
    if (packet == null || receiver == null) return;
    var empty = messageHandler.PacketQueueForSend.IsEmpty;
    packet.ClientTcp = receiver;
    messageHandler.PacketQueueForSend.Enqueue(packet);

    if (empty)
        await messageHandler.PacketSender();
}
```

Отсюда множественный вызов получается, а **нужно чтобы только в случае если до этого очередь была пуста**. Все это было придумано, чтобы в Stream одного сокета не писали несколько потоков, а не деле идея не додумана. Если есть способ проще, то просьба рассказать мне о нем.

Comment: Вы случайно не [producer/consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105) заново изобретаете?

Comment: Именно то что нужно. Если говорить относительно первого ответа про BlockingCollection.
Получается мне нужно запустить свой аналогичный метод Consumer в отдельном потоке и он будет в бесконечном режиме ждать пока в коллекции что-то появится? А потокам, которые добавляют в коллекцию элементы не запрещать в него добавление?

Comment: Именно так, он будет ждать добавления. Можно, кстати, и несколько параллельных Consumer'ов.

Comment: «А потокам, которые добавляют в коллекцию элементы не запрещать в него добавление?» — вот этого не понял

Comment: Вот этим CompleteAdding, так понял, что после нее коллекция становится ReadOnly и нужно будет создать новый экземпляр BlockingCollection. 
Насчет параллельных Consumer'ов, сейчас так и получается, что обработчиков очереди становится много.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, главное, что после `CompleteAdding` `Consumer` больше не будет ждать появления нового элемента, а просто завершит цикл

Comment: Вот! Мне этого не нужно.

Comment: Тогда не вызывайте `CompleteAdding` раньше времени :)