# модель производитель - потребитель в контексте потоков

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, unix

Есть два потока, один из которых выступает производителем данных, а второй - их потребителем. Так же есть общий пул данных, например, массив структур типа :

```
struct D{
char fl_busy;
char data[256];
};
```

Поток-производитель выполняет только следующие 3 действия :

1. просматривает пул на предмет наличия пустого элемента (перебирает
   элементы до первого, в котором *fl_busy* = 0);
2. если такой элемент найден, помечает его занятым (*fl_busy* = 1),
   заполняет оставшуюся часть структуры *data*;
3. передает указатель на только что заполненный элемент пула
   потоку-потребителю (например, добавляет указатель в очередь, которую
   мониторит поток-потребитель).

Поток-потребитель, в свою очередь, выполняет только свои 3 действия :

1. ожидает, когда в очереди появится указатель на элемент пула, и
   изымает его из очереди;
2. получив указатель, как-то обрабатывает данные *data* в структуре
   (модифицирует, копирует куда-то);
3. помечает данные элемент пула свободным (*fl_busy* = 0);

Вопросы:

1. Какие вообще механизмы лучше использовать в подобных задачах, чтобы
   не снижать производительность, но при этом добиться, чтобы значение
   флагов в элементах пула было видимым и актуальным в обоих потоках и
   гарантировать правильную последовательность действий в потоках? 
   *Volatile* в каждом элементе пула использовать совсем не хочется из-за
   производительности, да и все проблемы он, вероятно, не решит. Кажется,
   что тут имеет смысл использовать барьеры памяти, но я пока плохо с
   ними освоилась, и мне не помешал бы пример.
2. Нужны ли тут атомарные функции и объявление *fl_busy* как *atomic*, с
   учетом что флаг всего байт?

Comment: Один поток ставит флаг, другой его снимает. А нужен ли вообще этот флаг? Производитель получает данные и помещает в потокобезопасную коллекцию. Потребитель выгребает данные из коллекции и обрабатывает. Осталось найти готовую подходящую коллекцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нужен! В коллекцию передаются не данные, а указатель на них, без этого флага первый поток не поймет, когда элемент пула с этим указателем можно использовать повторно

Comment: @Abyx, да, конечно, второй поток должен был ожидать на condition variable

Comment: @margosh: Тогда без мьютекса никак. Вот вам пример на pthreads: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428867

Comment: @VladD, да это понятно как раз, мьютекс и cond. var. будут защищать очередь, меня другое интересует - мне нужно чтобы не получилось, что поток-потребитель обработал данные в элементе пула, и пометил его как свободный, а поток-производитель не заметил, что элемент освободился. Заходите в чат ;)

Comment: @margosh: Я с телефона, так что буду писать медленно :)

Comment: @margosh: А в каком чате обсуждение?

Comment: @VladD, в С++ \ С

Comment: @margosh, (только сейчас добрался до компа) **volatile** в такой схеме обязателен (и ни с какими  memory fence это не связано). Без volatile на элемент структуры (точнее указатель, по которому вы будете его менять) компилятор (скажем с `-O2`) попросту может оставить новое значение в регистре и не писать его  в память. Именно компилятор. Так что, в любом случае компилируйте такие кусочки с `-S` и смотрите, что есть команда записывающая регистр в память.

Comment: @avp этот подход сильно устарел. Просто нужно помечать переменную, в которую лезут многие потоки, как atomic
В С++20 так вообще - volatile будет deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Прямо отвечая на ваши требования -  Вам нужно использовать `std::atomic_flag`.

Он гарантирует вам атомарность и когерентность операций. `volatile` - это устаревший подход из мира `C++98`, когда компиляторы ничего не знали о том, что программа может выполняться параллельно.

Относительно барьеров памяти. Если вы внимательно почитаете, какие параметры кушают атомарные переменные в `C++`, вы там эти самые `memory orders` увидите. По умолчанию они как раз обеспечивают то, что вы просите - когерентность.

Что касается вопроса 2, нужно. Иначе компилятор ничего не будет знать о том, что это значение может поменять другой поток. Идея о том, что *якобы* однобайтовое значение может поменяться за одну инструкцию, в целом, неверна.

Потому что это может быть, как минимум

```
mov память, регистр
add регистр
mov регистр, память
```

А теперь пришел планировщик, и после первого `mov` все сломал.

Формально, ваш обмен данными между производителем и *поедателем*, можно организовать без мьютексов, только на двух [атомарных указателях и кольцевом буфере](https://github.com/BG4444/pipeOverRingBuffer/blob/master/ringBuffer.c).

Однако учтите, что тот код - под микроконтроллер. Там я специально выгонял ассемблерный листинг, чтобы проверить, что запись в указатели происходит за одну инструкцию.

К этому коду у меня есть формальное доказательство его корректности, так что, в порядке эксперимента, можете переделать его под себя и использовать.

Answer (score 0):

*флаг всего байт* - какая разница?! Хоть полбайта! :-) АТОМАРНОСТЬ в многопотоковом программировании означает нечто  совсем другое. Конкретно, вот вы пишете:

1. проверям fl_busy = 0
2. помечаем fl_busy = 1

Вы понимаете, что в момент МЕЖДУ пунктом 1 и пунктом 2 может произойти прерывание и управление передано будет на другую нить? И вся программа рухнет..

Так вот АТОМАРНОЙ будет операция, объединяющая пункты 1 и 2 и которая не может быть прервана. Эта операция в большинстве ОС реализована с помощью механизма мьютексов. Читайте !!! Это большая и сложная тема.

Comment: Вы плохо вникли в описанную задачу, так что Ваш ответ с вопросом мало общего имеет

Comment: **Вы плохо вникли в описанную задачу** Может быть... :-( Но вообще-то, задача производитель/потребитель настолько стара и настолько изучена, что вникать тут уже, вроде-бы, некуда. Вот, можете посмотерть студенческую работу на эту тему: http://www.hpcc.unn.ru/multicore/materials/os/MultiCore-OS-Lab1-ProducerConsumer.pdf

Comment: Вы опять упираете на мьютексы, но вообще-то это довольно медленное решение, которое меня не устраивает, меня в данном случае интересуют lock-free варианты и обеспечение когерентности кэша в потоках при помощи менее затратных по сравнению с мьютексами средств

Comment: **это довольно медленное решение, которое меня не устраивает** - странно.... Насколько мне известно, это самаое распространённое решение проблемы, которым пользуются практических во всех программных системах с параллелизмом. Включая самые мощные серверы. Ну, если Вам кажется, что это медленно, попробуйте напрямую использовать семафоры (man 7 sem_overview). Собственно говоря, мьютекс - это обёртка над семафорамами, имеющая всего 2 состояния: 0 и 1. Попробуйте их. Кстати, для задачи производитель/потребитель они очень подходят.