# Возможно ли, используя net 3.5 создать пул потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть ли пример создания пула потоков, без использования TPL и treadPool, где в качестве основы взяты thread?

Для вакансии джуниора прислали тестовое задание. Ограничили 3.5 фреймворком и попросили написать эффективное многопоточное приложение по упаковке/распаковке файлов. Написал, но появилась одна трудность: каждый поток создаётся, выполняет функцию и умирает.

Меня попросили реализовать пул потоков, в котором потоки могут быть переиспользованы многократно. Перекопав гугл я в данный момент в тупике. 
Подскажите куда копать, где искать, как поступить?

Ссылка на написанную программу тут: https://github.com/GarrusEn/PracticalAndTests/tree/master/ZipCompress/ZipCompress

Comment: Книга "C# 2010 Ускоренный курс для профессионалов", Трей Нэш, страница 389 - пример пула потоков. Желательно, конечно, всю главу про многопоточность проштудировать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Comment: Если для вас не ограничивали в использование ThreadPool, то почему бы им не воспользоваться? В .Net 3.5 этот тип уже присутствует.

Comment: @AndreiS. Как раз таки ограничили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [паттерном Producer/Consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105). Класс `ThreadPool` (ваш) будет поставщиком. Он будет поставлять `Action`'ы в очередь заданий. В свою очередь, каждый из потоков, которые вы запустите, должны будут работать потребителями: каждый полученный `Action` нужно просто запускать. Вот вроде бы и всё.

```
class ThreadPool
{
    readonly ProducerConsumer<Action> q = new ProducerConsumer<Action>();

    void Run()
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(Consumer);
            t.Start();
            threads.Add(t);
        }
    }

    void Consumer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action a = q.Dequeue();
            if (a == null)
                break;
            a(); // добавьте try/catch по вкусу
        }
    }

    public void QueueUserTask(Action a)
    {
        if (a == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
        q.Enqueue(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Я правильно понял, consumer - это тот алгоритм, который должен выполнять каждый поток?

Comment: @Garrus_En: Именно так!

Comment: @Garrus_En: Пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться классом BackgroundWorker он доступен с .Net 2.0.

```
SynchronizationContext context;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    StartPool();
}

private void StartPool()
{
    foreach (int tp in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
    {
        StartBW(tp);
    }
}

private void StartBW(int tp)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (obj, e) => WorkZip(tp);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void WorkZip(int e)
{
    try
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int ind_rnd = rnd.Next(100, 300);
        Thread.Sleep(ind_rnd);
        context.Send(
            (par)=>
            {
                icMessage.Items.Add("Working zip = " + par);
            }, e);
    }catch(Exception x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error work {0} : {1}", e, x.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавте в ответ пример.