# Оптимизация работы Parallel.ForEach

Tags: .net, async-await

Добрый день, коллеги.

Написал работающий алгоритм получения и обработки данных по типичному сценарию **producer/consumer**, хочу продвинуться дальше.

Одна из producer-процедур получает список файлов и запускает `Parallel.ForEach` по каждому элементу списка. Каждая итерация состоит из трех блоков:

1. Скачивание файла
2. Чтение файла через COM интерфейс Excel и получение двумерного массива строк
3. Создание объекта по каждой строке массива и отправка его в `BlockingCollection`

Файлов несколько сотен, понятно, что запускать экземпляр Excel для чтения каждого файла бессмысленно и затратно, поэтому **пункт 2** заключен в критическую секцию. Можно, конечно, использовать семафор и обрабатывать файлы несколькими экземплярами Excel, но это другая история и я не хочу этого касаться.

В текущем состоянии цикл держит активными 4 задачи (по количеству процессоров), то есть параллельность получается малоэффективной: быстро скачиваются 4 файла,  задачи ждут по очереди блокировку и алгоритм получается практически синхронным.

Вопрос: как поставить задачу по первой итерации `Parallel.ForEach` в режим ожидания, чтобы начала работать вторая, а потом вернуться и доделать первую? Пытаясь использовать Await, поток выполнения выходит из цикла и я получаю кашу.

Эффективный результат был бы примерно таким: скачалось 4 файла, запустилась блокировка на Excel, остальные три задачи ушли в фон, скачалось три файла, скачалось три файла, обработался массив из 1-й задачи, запустилась блокировка во 2-й задаче, скачалось 2 файла...

Хочется еще попробовать отказаться от `Parallel.ForEach`, разбить алгоритм на три синхронных `For Each` и связать их через 2 `consume-коллекции`, чтобы обеспечить примерно такой ход выполнения, который описал выше. Или вовсе написать три функции и увязать их напрямую через `Yield` безо всяких лишних коллекций, так будет еще быстрее. Но это также другая история, которой в рамках этого вопроса касаться не буду.

В данном случае мне не хватает IQ для того, чтобы самостоятельно разобраться с вопросом асинхронности внутри итераций `Parallel.ForEach`, очень надеюсь на ваши квалифицированные советы, которые смогут поднять мой уровень.

Спасибо

Comment: Сразу оговорюсь по поводу выбора в пользу критической секции и использования 1 инстанс-приложения Excel вместо запуска Excel на каждый файл. Замеры на сервере с 16 ядрами показали увеличение времени работы в два раза по сравнению с критической секцией. 
Данный подход я рассматривать не буду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать длинный конвейер.

1. Очередь адресов для скачивания. Producer берёт список и укладывает в очередь, consumer'ы берут адрес из очереди из очереди, скачивают файл, и кладут путь к файлу (или его контент) во вторую очередь. (Для этой второй очереди consumer'ы выступают в роли producer'ов.)
2. Очередь скачанных файлов. У каждого consumer'а по экземпляру Excel'я, он задирает из очереди скачанный файл, скармливает его Excel'ю и забирает результат в виде двумерного массива. После чего каждую строку массива добавляет в очередь массивов, и удаляет файл. Количество consumer'ов здесь равно нужному количеству экземпляров Excel'я.
3. Очередь строк — это то, чем у вас сейчас является единственный экземпляр `BlockingCollection`.

`Parallel.ForEach` и `await` становятся по идее не нужными.

---

Для реализации очередей стоит использовать `BlockingCollection`, как описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105).

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет. В англ.статье https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach читаю про то, что `TPL` и `async\await` по факту несовместимы и акробатика с `await` внутри `Parallel` циклов не получится никогда. Вместо этого советуют применить `TPL Dataflow`. Выглядит громоздко и на первый взгляд сложно, но попробовать в деле интересно

Comment: @ИванЛазарев: Ну это как бы не вполне факт, т. к. async/await базируется на TPL. Но да, TPL Dataflow — это, вероятно, хороший вариант для вашего случая.

Comment: в общем, `TPL Dataflow` имеет смысл внедрять в каких-то больших проектах с  действительно сложной архитектурой, в которой сценарий **producer/consumer** не статичен. Для моего проекта это "из пушки по воробьям", но в целом я своей цели достиг и понял суть. 

Переделал проект, добавив две коллекции для связи 3 задач через итератор, все работает быстро вопреки моим сомнениям - коллекции ведь в полный рост не материализуются, итераторы держат в памяти только объекты, над которыми работают в данный момент. В итоге 45 секунд работы приложения превратились в 38 :D

Comment: И еще - очередь не стал делать, все работает через `BlockingCollection`, так как порядок следования данных не имеет значения. От `Parallel.ForEach` также не отказался и использовал конструкцию для массированной загрузки файлов с сервера. От блокировки для Excel отказался, просто итерируясь по скачанным файлам в синхронном `For Each`. Все работает стабильно

Comment: @ИванЛазарев: Ну я под оочередью и имел в виду `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @VladD из TPL async/await взял только таски. А вот с методами TPL он действительно не дружит.

Comment: @andreycha: Ну, таски как бы и были построены с прицелом на async/await, как я понимаю. Из [всего TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) плохо соотносится с `Parallel.For` и его друзьями, с Dataflow вроде работает хорошо, с PLINQ плохо, но с приходом в C# 8 [`IAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43) с неплохими шансами станет хорошо.