# Потоки и Thread.sleep()

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пытаюсь написать планировщик. Необходимо чтобы два потока (функции `LoopGetTask` и `LoopExecTask`) выполнялись параллельно, но `Thread.Sleep` не дает желаемого результата (выполняется только одна из функций). Создается впечатление, что `Thread.Sleep` влияет на оба потока независимо от того, где вызывается

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private Thread ThrExecTask;
    private Thread ThrGetTask;

    private Queue<int> taskList = new Queue<int>();

    public Scheduler()
        {
            work = false;
            ThrExecTask = new Thread(LoopExecTask);

            ThrGetTask = new Thread(LoopGetTask);

            ThrExecTask.Start();
            ThrGetTask.Start();
        }
    }

    private void LoopGetTask()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                //получить список задач... insert into taskList
                Thread.Sleep(20000);

            }
        }



    private void LoopExecTask()
    {
        while(true)
        { 
            //выполнить задачу exec taskList.first
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили что выполняется только один из потоков? И где у вас синхронизация доступа к общей переменной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, выполняются ли потоки параллельно или нет, зависит от операционной системы и от количества логических процессоров в системе. Обычно, даже если у вас всего один логический процессор, система забирает время от времени управление у одного потока, и отдаёт другому, таким образом, потоки бегут практически параллельно.

Этим вы не можете управлять (и не должны).

`Thread.Sleep` исключает поток на время из этой схемы: данный поток просто не выбирается к выполнению системой разделения времени. На другие потоки это прямо не влияет. Разве что косвенно, если другие потоки дожидаются этого потока.

Иллюзия того, что потоки ведут себя «не так», может быть от того, что вы используете разделяемые данные (`taskList`) из разных потоков без синхронизации. Так делать запрещено.

---

По поводу корректной имплементации очереди заданий, загляните сюда: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105).