# Как решить задачу «читателя и писателя» с буферным пулом (динамическим массивом)?

Tags: c, многопоточность, динамические-массивы

Сама задача:
Рассмотрим взаимодействие двух потоков, один из которых пишет данные в буферный пул, а другой считывает их из пула. Буферный пул состоит из N буферов, каждый содержит одну запись. В общем случае поток-писатель и поток-читатель имеют разные скорости (длительности выполнения операция чтения и записи) и обращаются к пулу с переменной интенсивностью (начинают выполнять операции в случайные моменты времени с равномерным законом распределения). Для правильной работы поток-писатель приостанавливается, когда все буферы заняты, и переходит в активное состояние при наличии хотя бы одного свободного буфера. Поток-читатель приостанавливается, когда все буферы пусты, и активизируется, когда появляется, по крайней мере, одна запись.
Количество потоков-писателей и читателей, длительности операций чтения и записи, размер буферного пула устанавливаются пользователем.

Буферный пул в данном случае - динамический массив, если я верно понял преподавателя. По условию задачи поток-читатель и поток-писатель приостанавливаются в ожидании непустого и пустого буфера соответственно.

Каким образом реализовать проверку на наличие пустого-непустого буфера, чтобы активизировались потоки?
Каким образом передавать в поток-читатель или в поток-писатель адрес освободившегося буфера для работы с ним?

Основной принцип работы потоков схож с примером на википедии ([тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85#%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85_(%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2))), но можно решить и с 2 семафорами.

Comment: Вот вам готовая имплементация: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428867/10105. Править её точно под вашу лабу, заменяя condition variable на семафоры, думаю, вряд ли кто-то будет.