# BlockingCollection - как не блокировать поток

Tags: c#, многопоточность, коллекции, очередь

Применение `BlockingCollection`, используя подход, когда элементы вытаскиваются из очереди(например `ConcurrentQueue`), используя метод `Take` в цикле -  всегда блокирует поток. Очевидно, что процессорное время не занимается, однако поток все же занят и не может использоваться для выполнения других задач. Какая есть альтернатива, когда нужно последовательно вычитывать элементы из очереди и при этом не блокировать поток? Конечно, можно сделать велосипед, накрутить событий или чего-нибудь еще, но хотелось бы понять, нет ли каких-либо стандартных способов это сделать, кроме как использовать `BlockingCollection` и метод `Take`.

P.S. Есть метод `TryTake`, но я не могу найти решение с его использованием, эквивалентное использованию Take и при этом неблокирующее поток.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам на самом деле нужен класс [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) из библиотеки [Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (nuget-пакет `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow`).

Этот класс заменяет собой `BlockingCollection<T>`, и позволяет асинхронный доступ:

```
await queue.ReceiveAsync()
```

Таким образом, поток не будет заблокирован. Но у вас получится async-интерфейс.

Больше примеров с работающим кодом есть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431145/10105).

---

Ещё одним вариантом является async-обёртка над `IProducerCosumerCollection` из `AsyncEx` Стивена Клири: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncCollection

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Правильно ли я понимаю, что BufferBlock это тоже враппер? То есть во внутрь я могу засунуть свою реализацию IProducerCosumerCollection?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Насколько я понимаю, нет, он сам по себе готовый примитив. Но его можно конфигурировать. А для чего вам своя реализация?

Comment: Своя реализация для приоритетной очереди, которую я и использую в рамках BlockingCollection. Хотя, конечно, в рамках Dataflow тоже наверняка что-то есть.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Добавил ещё один вариант в ответ.

Comment: VladD, спасибо Вам огромное! Интересно будет разобраться, как это работает. Как я понимаю, автор из Вашего ответа по сути и взял BlockingCollection и сделал ее асинхронный вариант.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Ага, именно так.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Есть некий набор адаптеров, каждый из которых запускает примерно такой код: запускается Async метод, внутри которого бесконечный while и await _queue.TakeAsync(). То есть у каждого адаптера своя очередь. Смотрю в диспетчере задач - потоки множатся. Может быть я делаю что-то не так? Я ожидал, что количество потоков будет расти только при большей нагрузке(то есть реальной активности), а в моменты ожидания их не будет.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Странно, не должны вроде. А можно какой-нибудь пример того, что вы делаете? И интересно, что за потоки? Может быть, это ThreadPool увидел активность и решил на всякий случай динамически подрасти заранее, чтобы потом не создавать потоки из-за нехватки? (Он так иногда делает.)

Comment: Да нет, все оказалось проще, потоки создавались в другом месте. Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: @Sleeeper: А, ну слава богу, одной загадкой меньше.