# Правильное создание асинхронного метода

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

У меня есть метод, который делит файл на части, моя задача состоит в том, чтобы не дожидаясь, полного разделения файла на части, начинать обрабатывать те части, которые на данный момент есть в папке.

Для этого сделал асинхронный метод, но как правильно его вызвать я не знаю, естественно при текущем вызове, он будет работать до того момента, пока работает метод разделения файла на части. Мне же нужно чтобы он работал, и после выполнения этого метода.

В данный момент, при разделении больших файлов на части, обрабатывается только часть файлов, остальные не успевают обработаться т.к метод CreateFileParts() заканчивает свою работу, и вместе с ним перестает вызываться CheckFilesAsync() (при этом, части файлов остались в папке и к ним нужно будет вернуться и обработать)

Возможно нужно создавать отдельный метод с бесконечным циклом? Подскажите как сделать это правильно

```
 void CreateFileParts() // метод разделения файла на части
    {               
        try
        {
                using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < countOfParts; i++)
                    {
                        using (FileStream fsWrite = new FileStream(@"parts\" + $"{i}_{fileName}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            if ((int)i == countOfParts - 1)
                            {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeLastPart];
                                fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOnePart];
                                fsRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                fsWrite.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                        }
                       CheckFilesAsync($"{i}_{fileName}"); // вызов асинхронного метода
                    }
                }                                          
            }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }              
    }

async Task CheckFilesAsync(string name)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
                var files = new DirectoryInfo(pathToFolder).GetFiles();
                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    if (item.Length == sizeOnePart || item.Length == sizeLastPart)
                    {
                       //do

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File not found!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Используйте паттерн [producer/consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794380/184217) ([еще ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/184217)) - один поток читает файл, делит его на части и записывает в потокобезопасную коллекцию имена получившихся файлов-частей. Другой поток выбирает из этой коллекции имена файлов и обрабатывает их. Внутри этого второго потока можно запускать несколько обрабатывающих потоков.

Comment: Но вам же уже говорили раньше, что делить файл на части неэффективно - накопители по природе своей последовательные устройства. Поэтому используйте тот же паттерн, но более эффективно: один поток читает файл по частям, и запускает с каждой частью обрабатывающий поток. Если проблема в исчерпании памяти, то просто читающий поток ждет, пока ранее запущенные обрабатывающие потоки завершатся. Не нужно создавать дополнительные файлы!

Comment: Вызов асинхронного метода без await - это плохо - исключение не поймается. И ловить все исключения без разбора - тоже плохо.