# Task и стабильность работы

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Для многопоточной обработки без ожидания использую

```
private void QQ(string str) {
    var outer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        ...
    });
}
```

При этом метод `QQ` может вызываться больше 10 раз в секунду.

Если я правильно понял, то `Task` каждый раз создаёт новый поток.

Будут ли какие-либо проблемы, если создавать по 20 потоков в секунду, и, если да, то как можно отвести для этого метода только 2-3 потока?

Знаю, что можно создать лист, в который добавлять параметры для метода (в данном случае `string str`), создать 2 потока, которые берут инфу из листа, блокировать их, и разблокировать при добавлении новой инфы в лист, но это попахивает костылём.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-producer-consumer-pattern)

Comment: Используйте Task.Run, ваши задания будут выполняться на пуле потоков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не требуется какая-то экзотическая работа с потоками, то проще использовать `Task.Run(() => {});` 
По-умолчанию при работе с тасками новый поток не создается, а берется существующий из пула.

Таски как раз придуманы для того, чтобы не писать костыли с передачей параметров между потоками. По поводу проблем, тут нужно смотреть что у вас в `() => {}`. Но попробуйте без преждевременной оптимизации и сделайте сначала по-простому.