# Как записывать в файл из нескольких потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Задача: записывать в файл данные из нескольких потоков.

При последовательной записи (режим `Append`) работает без ошибок.

```
_waitWriteHandler.WaitOne();

using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(Destination, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)))
{
    bw.Write(data);
}

_waitWriteHandler.Set();
```

А если сначала создать файл:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(Destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)))
{
    bw.Write(new byte[destinationFileSize]);
}
```

И в разные места начать писать данные:

```
_waitWriteHandler.WaitOne();

using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(Destination, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)))
{
    bw.BaseStream.Position = position;
    bw.Write(data);
}

_waitWriteHandler.Set();
```

то выдает необработанное исключение, что файл уже используется другим процессом (причем дает часть данных записать, всегда по-разному).

Использую класс `Thread` и `AutoResetEvent` для синхронизации.

Comment: Напрямую писать в файл одновременно разными потоками не получится, хотя бы потому что это не логично, не говоря уже об ограничениях системы и др. Как вариант можно использовать временный буфер.

Comment: `FileShare.None` -- монопольный режим же, разве нет? да и вроде явно файл не закрываете после записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получать эксклюзивные права на запись в файл(`FileShare.None`), как вы и делаете, но постоянные переоткрытия файла с блокировкой будут очень узким местом.
Также придётся отлавливать `System.IO.IOException`, например, в бесконечном цикле, чтобы дождаться освобождения файла.

Лучше всего собирать данные в разных потоках, но писать в одном, специально для этого выделенном, через механизм очереди.
Скармливаете ему "задачи", а он их выполняет. (Это называется `producer-consumer`)

Comment: Благодарю за наводку. Помогло вот это решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern