# Подскажите по паттерну

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать чтобы каждый поток в моем приложении, сжимает и пишет данные независимо друг от друга. Прочитал, что для подобной организации есть паттерн Producer Consumer, где то есть вменяемое объяснение его построения? Так как смотрю в интернете и нахожу некоторые сведения, но они по разному сделаны, где то используется семафоры, где то события, в каждом из примеров всегда есть оговорка, мол, но возникает проблема. Если уважаемая публика мне поможет с или с пониманием правильным этого паттерна, на уровне как его сделать, или укажет нормальную информацию. Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern

Comment: Возможно вам поможет практика? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274223/implementing-producer-consumer-in-java