# Подскажите где ошибка в очереди

Tags: c#

Написал несколько методов, один читает файл по частям, далее все складываю в очередь необработанных блоков, следующий метод сжимает каждый блок, далее в цикле я кладу сжатые блоки в новую очередь готовых блоков. Потом соответственно, беру блоки из готовой очереди и просто пишу их в файл.

Но заметил такую штуку, до того как были готовы методы сжатия и до того как я добавлял сжатые блоки в готовую очередь, все было нормально. мой файл распадался на 32 части и эти части лежали в очереди для необработанных блоков,но после подключения метода ,который сжимает данные и эти данные я далее добавляю в очередь с готовым материалом, у меня почему то в очереди с необработанными блоками их количество упало в два раза, было 32 блока, стало 16, и по логике я понимаю, что  в очереди с готовыми блоками у меня должно быть такое же количество блоков, они по размеру будут другие, а количество не измениться. Подскажите что не так в логике или исполнении.

Вот код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 string path = @"d:\Black Widow.m4a";
 string path_compres = @"d:\Compress.gz";



// создаем очередь c блоками ланных
        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> queue_block = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>();
// создаем очередь с готовыми обработанными блоками
        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> readyQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>();


// открываем поток
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))


// добавляем в очередь блоки

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> block in Read_Blockk(fs))
        {
            queue_block.Enqueue(block);

        }



    // сжимаем и добавляем в готовую очередь        
            while (queue_block.Peek().Key<queue_block.Count)
            {
                int count = 0;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> ready_block in COmpress(count, queue_block.Dequeue().Value))
                {
                    readyQueue.Enqueue(ready_block);
                    count++;
                }

            }

     // пишем в файл блоки



            while (readyQueue.Count!=0)
            {

                Write_Final_File(path_compres,readyQueue.Dequeue().Value);
            }



Console.ReadKey();



        }



        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,byte[]>> Read_Blockk(Stream stream)
        {
            const int size_block=1024 * 1024; // определяем размер буфера=1мб

            int index = 0; // номер блока
            while (stream.Position<stream.Length)
            {
                // выделяем память под массив буффера.
                byte[] buffer=new byte[System.Math.Min(size_block,stream.Length-stream.Position)];

                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(index++,buffer);
            }

        }



        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> COmpress(int index,byte[] block)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var gzStream=new GZipStream(ms,CompressionMode.Compress))
            {

                int ind = index;
                gzStream.Write(block,0,block.Length);
                gzStream.Close();

                 yield return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(ind++,ms.ToArray());

                }


            }

        public static void Write_Final_File(string path,    byte[] ReadyBlock)
        {
            using (var fsWrite = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))

            fsWrite.Write(ReadyBlock,0,ReadyBlock.Length);


        }


        }



    }
```

Comment: 4 раза пытался прочесть абзац и сдался :) можете в вопросе суть проблемы выделить и показать место в коде, в котором что-то пошло не так?

Comment: @gil9red Эмоции)), если выполнить только    queue_block.Enqueue(block); то частей блоков в очереди будет 32, это правильно, файл разбился на 32 части и сложился в очередь для необработанных блоков. А вот когда делаю компрессию,  и дальше кладу в очередь для готовых блоков, у меня получается 16 блоков в очереди, вопрос куда делись остальные

Comment: Не дочитал вопрос, но вы глядели в сторону [DataFlow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428327/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern/) ?

Comment: @tym32167 Да умом понимаю что именно  это меня спасет, а вменяемой инфы пока не нашел, ну по крупицам собираю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод Compress не содержит циклов, но возвращаете вы `IEnumerable` через `yield return` мне кажется тут должен просто возвращаться `KeyValuePair`. Так же мне не понятны ваши манипуляции с индексом блока, мне кажется с индексом ничего делать не нужно.

```
public static KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> Compress(int index,byte[] block)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        gzStream.Write(block,0,block.Length);
        gzStream.Close();

        return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(index, ms.ToArray()); //Зачем тут был ind++ мне не понятно
    }
}
```

Так же я бы поменял сжатие и добавление в готовую очередь, мне кажется вы тут перемудрили.

```
// сжимаем и добавляем в готовую очередь 
while (queue_block.Count > 0) //тут было вообще что-то непонятное
{
    var block = queue_block.Dequeue();
    var compressedBlock = Compress(block.Key, block.Value);
    readyQueue.Enqueue(compressedBlock);
}
```

Comment: Да как раз я и думаю, что мне с индексами блоков делать, и через yield я возвращаюсь для того, чтобы в форыче все быстро обработать, но я наверное не прав

Comment: В этом нет смысла, так как внутри происходила обработка только одного элемента. То есть вы по сути оборачивали один элемент в IEnumerable, а потом делали цикл над коллекцией из одного элемента.

Comment: Да уж, учусь потихоньку, попробую сейчас переправить

Comment: Да теперь блоки все на месте, только почему то теперь архив файла весит больше чем сам исходный файл, это же метод компрессии, снова где то перемудрил,

Comment: Ну тут нужно смотреть, что за файл, многие файлы по умолчанию сжаты более подходящими под тип данных алгоритмами. Особенно это касается видео и аудио файлов, их сжатие как правило бессмысленно, так как они уже максимально сжаты кодеком. Сжатие хорошо работает над текстовыми файлами.