# Как ограничить очередь от переполнения

Tags: c#

Подскажите как правильно организовать защиту от переполнения очереди, суть в том чтобы очередь не кушала всю память при работе метода. Вот метод, в котором я прочитав блоки данных из файла добавляю их в очередь.
`Read_Blockk(fs)` это метод, который разбивает файл на куски и читает их.
Идея такая, как бы сделать так, чтобы в этом методе проверялась полнота очереди и если очередь полная то метод бы замирал, или поток в котором метод работает замирал до тех пор, пока очередь не станет свободной или в очереди не появится свободное место.Замысел такой, чтобы очередь не росла в размерах и не использовала всю память. Может есть эффективнее механизмы.

```
// создаем очередь c блоками данных
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> queue_block = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>(); 

// добавляем в очередь считанные блоки  
public static void ADD_Block_to_Queue(Queue<KeyValuePair<int,byte[]>> queue_block,Stream fs)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> block in Read_Blockk(fs))
    {
        queue_block.Enqueue(block);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/178779

Comment: В вопросе по ссылке есть что-то похожее, только с защитой от исчерпания очереди, а не от переполнения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Мне нужно, чтобы очередь не была полной и не росла в памяти, я ее хочу ограничить, а  в вашей ссылке идет реализация ограничения очереди в Producer-Consumer, а у меня просто очередь с данными, и мне нужно как то научить метод, который добавляет данные в очередь, следить за полнотой очереди.

Comment: Возьмите ActionBlock из Dataflow, и не изобретайте велосипед, размер очереди там параметром можно задать

Comment: @PrimusSingularis я не могу использовать Dataflow, по условиям задачи, и нужно , чтобы все работало на .net 3,5

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch в рамках простой очереди это невозможно. Метод же не может завершить свою работу раньше чем все прочитает. Или может? Если может - просто пишите return

Comment: @PavelMayorov Сейчас этот метод работает в основном потоке, или мне создать, поток отдельный для этого метода, ну вот пробовал не работает. Остальные потоки которые обрабатывают данные организованы через Producer Consumer

Comment: @PavelMayorov сама моя программка вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861955/Потоки-подскажите-как-проверить-очередь-на-переполнения?rq=1)