# Как правильно вытаскивать элемент по ключу из ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

У меня есть два метода получения элемента по ключу :

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte[]> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte[]>();
private bool _completed = false;
```

Первый :

```
public bool TryGetValueByKey(out byte[] data)
{
    lock (_writingLocker)
    {
        while (!_writingDictionary.ContainsKey(_index))
        {
            if (_completed)
            {
                data = new byte[0];
                return false;
            }
            Monitor.Wait(_writingLocker);                                        
        }
        data = _writingDictionary[_index++];
        Monitor.PulseAll(_writingLocker);
        return true;
    }
}

 public void SetCompleted()
        {
            lock (_writingLocker)
            {
                _completed = true;
                Monitor.PulseAll(_writingLocker);
            }
        }
```

Второй :

```
public bool GetValueByKey(out byte[] data) => _dictionary.TryGetValue(_index++, out data);
```

Используется ConcurrentDictionary в обоих случаях, второй меня привлекает гораздо больше, но вопрос, насколько он безопасен?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` - потокобезопасная коллекция, потому вытаскивать из неё элемент - потокоюбехопасно. А вот увеличивать какой то ваш счетчик `_index++` без какой-либо синхронизации потокобазопасным не назвать.

Comment: т.е. первый метод более удачный? Есть ли у вас какая-либо идея как сделать это более изящно? я ничего не придумал за два- три часа.

Comment: Что думаете над тем. что бы использовать нечто подобное? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int32__

Comment: по тому куску кода, что вы показали, ничего не ясно, ни для чего эта структура данных, ни что у ней внутри есть, ни для чего этот index нужен, потому ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: делаю gzip многопоточный, который блоками архивирует и так далее)

Comment: и вы все блоки просто в памяти держите?

Comment: да, по крайней мере я так понял, это требуется в задании, если памяти не хватает, бросать ексепшен. Ну, я так понимаю.

Comment: ок, но вот это вам для чего `ConcurrentDictionary`? И что за index и для чего он? Что вообще этот ваш класс делает, откуда вы методы показали?

Comment: Это, по идее Consumers по паттерну.Producer/Consumers, предполагалось что здесь вся логика добавления и удаления из очереди/словаря.

Comment: В очередь я помещаю блоки, на которые разбил файл. В словарь же, помещаю вытащенные из очереди данные , по типу [блок,значение]

Comment: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)

Comment: `И что за index и для чего он?`

Comment: пробежаться по всем блокам словаря.

Comment: чтобы пробежаться по всем блокам, у словаря есть `Values`, вам не нужен для этого индекс.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90221/discussion-between-tetsua-keito-and-tym32167).