# Многопоточность C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Сalculator calc = new Сalculator(3);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
public class Сalculator
{
    public List<Info> result;
    private double Start_x;
    Thread task1;
    Thread task2;
    public Object locker = new object();

    public Сalculator(double Start_X)
    {
        this.Start_x = Start_X;
        result = new List<Info>();
        task1 = new Thread(Result);
        task2 = new Thread(Shoow);
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();

    }

    public void Result()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                double y = 23 * Math.Pow(Start_x, 2) - 23;
                Add_To_Collection(Start_x, y);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    public void Shoow()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result[result.Count - 1].ToString());
                Start_x += 0.1;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add_To_Collection(double X, double Y)
    {
        result.Add(new Info(X,Y));
    }
}
```

Я разобрался с тем, что если мне необходимо работать с 1 объектом(в моём случае это коллекцией), мне необходимо создать объект и блокировать с начало в 1 потоке, потом в 2, что бы данные поступали и выходили корректно, один за другим. Но если я уберу `Thread.Slep` всё совершенно рушится( и выводится беспорядочно.
как это возможно исправить. Либо есть более простая вариация реализации много поточности в моём случае.

Comment: вы пытаетесь выехать на таймингах, когда вам нужен [producer-consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)

Comment: @tym32167, да, я это понимаю, но не понимаю почему так получается. Если я "забрал объект" не даю ему доступ, 2 поток должен ждать освобождения. Освободил, 2 поток взял его 1 поток стоит. Почему так не происходит, либо я не правильно понял?

Comment: если я верно помню (так тчо сами перепроверье это), но `lock` не дает вам очереди. То есть вот есть 2 потока, оба ждут `lock` секцию, который из них начнет обрабатываться первым, когда `lock` освободится? Ответ - любой, никакой очереди тут нет. То есть у вас потоки могут чередоваться как и `1-2-1-2-1`, так и `1-1-1-2-2-1-1`. Когда вы добавили `Thread.Sleep(500);`, то вы даете время второму потоку зайти в `lock`, пока первый ждет конца таймера. Поэтому у вас после 1 всегда идет 2, но вот после 2 что пойдет - опять не определено. (1 = Result(), 2=Shoow())

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо большое

Comment: На здоровье :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я правильно понял в """

Comment: @Grundy, я прочитал все реализации какие там есть, вот, что я понял, но не факт что правильно, по 1 реализации, которая более мне понятна: понял, что у нас есть очередь потоков основной, 1 и 2 созданные. Созданные вызываются по очереди, этой очередью "управляет" наша коллекция, НО, я не понимаю до сих пор, как же мне реализовать, что бы в двух созданных потоках, в 1 производить расчёты и записывать в коллекцию, а в 2 потоке выводить эту информацию на консоль((((

Comment: Так непонятно, что за 1 реализация.

Comment: @Grundy, называется «Реализация С#»

Comment: Через BlockingCollection? Там вроде @VladD уже пояснил :)

Comment: @Grundy , дада) я уже тучу информации прочитал) осталось уложить по полкам. Спасибо и тебе за помощь))