# Многопоточный Produce/Consumer

Tags: java, многопоточность

Дали задачу, но чего-то никак не могу понять как ее реализовать.

Есть `producer`, например, 25 потоков должно быть.
Есть `consumer`, например, 5 потоков должно быть.

producer посылает в очередь сообщение, получает оттуда `String` возвращается в producer.

consumer должен вычитывать эту очередь.

Размер сообщений, который будет оправлен, например, 500, после чего, видимо, `ExecutorService/ThreadPool` должен умереть для `producer`. Для `consumer` он должен работать до того момента, пока очередь не будет пуста.

Я всё не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы
1) все потоки стартовали одновременно
2) как запустить новые потоки в consumer

Вот так у меня примерно в main

```
public class Main{

private ExecutorService prodService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25, prodFactory);
private ExecutorService conService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, conFactory);

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        Starter bean = (Starter) context.getBean("starter");
        bean.doit();
 }

 private void doit() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            prodService.execute(() -> {
                 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    makeSmth();
                 }
            });
        conService.execute(() -> {doSmthTo();});
        }
 }

}
```

По факту, там у меня еще много чего страшного и не понятного, но я не знаю куда это всё внедрять)

Comment: `producer посылает в очередь сообщение, получает оттуда String возвращается в producer.` не понятно как и зачем producer'у что то получать

Comment: мне [вот тут](https://dzone.com/articles/the-evolution-of-producer-consumer-problem-in-java) послений пример приглянулся

Comment: если придете к какому то нормальному результату, будет неплохо добавить пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)

Comment: @tym32167, знать бы, нормальный это пример или нет ) Получать он должен для того, что задача такая была поставлена. А реализацию из вашего примера я видел, но она мне не очень помогла( Всё еще ищу что-то путное. Кстати, почему тот пример тогда не добавить в stack-wiki?

Comment: знать бы что такое stack-wiki )

Comment: это я так ту ссылку описал) википедия stackOverFlow ну или вопросы которые получили уйму плюсов

Comment: ну я тот пример не буду добавлять, так как он на Java, а я не пишу на Java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал примерно так.

```
class Stater {

public static boolean STOP = false;
private Producer producer;
private Consumer consumer;
private ExecutorService prodService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PRODUCER_NUMBER, taxiFactory);
private ExecutorService conService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONSUMER_NUMBER, clientFactory);


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        Starter bean = (Starter) context.getBean("starter");
        bean.doit();
 }

 private void doit() {

    for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_NUMBER; i++) {
        prodService.execute(() -> producer.get());
        conService.execute(() -> consumer.run());
    }

    Starter.STOP = true;
    producerService.shutdown();
    consumerService.shutdown();
 }
}


class Common {

private Queue<Message> emergencyQueue;
private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;

   public void insertOrder(Message message) {
        if (!blockingQueue.offer(message)) {
            emergencyQueue.add(message);
        }
    }

   public Message getOrder() {

        if (emergencyQueue.isEmpty()) {
            if (!blockingQueue.isEmpty()) {
                return blockingQueue.poll();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return emergencyQueue.poll();
        }
    }

   public boolean shouldStop() {
        return blockingQueue.isEmpty() && emergencyQueue.isEmpty() && Starter.STOP;
    }   
}


class Consumer implements Runnable{

private Common common;

   public void run(){
       common.insertOrder(new Message());
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable{

private Common common;

   public void run(){

          while (!common.shouldStop()) {

              Message message=common.getOrder();

              if (message == null) {
               Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(TIME_TO_WAIT));
            }

          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

LinkedBloсkingQueue - один из вариантов быстрого решения вопроса

Comment: вообще не тянет на решение. В `newFixedThreadPool` итак используется очередь, неважно связанная или случайная.