# Очередь из входных параметров одной функции

Tags: c#

Необходимо создать поток, в котором будет функция и очередь разных параметров и он будет по мере добавления в очередь данных параметров запускать функцию.
Задержка между добавлениями может быть и минута, поток просто должен висеть и использовать функцию, когда в очередь добавляются параметры.

Пример : У меня есть событие, которое добавляет в список `List` числовые значения от 1 и до 10. И в зависимости от значения мне необходимо вызывать функцию, например `void SetValue(int val)`. Событие вызывается в случайные моменты времени.

Comment: а можно хоть какой-нибудь пример, из которого будет понятно, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/218063

Comment: А зачем вам отдельный поток? По сути ведь консолька останавливается и ждет ввода при задании ей Console.Read();?

Comment: @Monomax добавил простой пример

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, в чем основная проблема? Можно перебирать список `List<params>` в цикле и запускать в зависимости от параметра в цикле `SetValue`.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я интересуюсь здесь, чтобы понять, как лучше и правильнее реализовать данный пример. Реализовать кое как я всегда смогу)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Возможно, вы правы, буду сейчас изучать это. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вам подойдёт такая вещь как ReactiveExtensions. Есть неплохой [сайт для изучения основ](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhyRx).

Ваш пример будет выглядеть на нём примерно так:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subject = new Subject<string>();
        var observable = subject.AsObservable(); //Чтобы пользователи не смогли закастить обратно
        Consume(observable);
        subject.OnNext("First");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        subject.OnNext("Second");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        subject.OnNext("Third");
        subject.OnCompleted();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Consume(IObservable<string> observable)
    {
        observable.Subscribe(
            Console.WriteLine,
            Console.WriteLine,
            () => Console.WriteLine("COmpleted!")); //Никак не обрабатываем IDisposable для простоты
    }
```

Но чаще всего удобнее бывает использовать фабричные методы Observable, чем напрямую взаимодействовать с  `Subject`.

Comment: А не проще создавать объект Queue, и допустим обрабатывать его каждые n минут, либо сделать привязку на изменение его?

Comment: @Ivan, прелесть RX заключается в том, что тебе не нужно заботится о работе с потоками и всем остальным. Ты получаешь удобный API, чтобы писать только бизнес логику. Ну и обработка происходит сразу, а не через n минут :3