# Построение конвейера обработки данных на BlockingCollection, где первая стадия ожидает данные от IObservable

Tags: c#

разбираюсь с `BlockingCollection` и построение конвейера обработки данных на его основе.
В официальном руководстве, приводятся пример первой стадии конвейера, в которой данные читаются из источника реализующего `IEnumerable`.
Я хотел разобраться, как сделать первую стадию конвейера, ожидающую получение данных от `IObservable`.

Для упрощения приведу только 2 стадии конвейера чтение и запись.
Сами методы обработки внутри стадии конвейера будут написаны заранее (до рефакторинга с применением `BlockingCollection`) и скорее всего будут асинхронные.
У меня вопрос по реализации метода `ReadStringsFromObservableSourse` - верно ли я его реализовал, т.е. обработка ошибок и отмена выполнения.

```
_ts.GetSourseStringObservable() - выдает IObservable<string>
```

В моем случае я вручную реализовал поступление данных через `GetSourseStringObservable()` используя класс `SensorPolling`, который периодически опрашивает какой-то ресурс.
Но, в реальном случае, скорее всего будут нативные реализации IObservable, например, ожидание данных с очередей обмена или каких то внешних ресурсов.
Вот меня интересуют все подводные камни которые могут быть в ожидании данных в конвейере.

```
public class Pipline
{
    private readonly TextSource _ts;       
    public Pipline(TextSource ts)
    {
        _ts = ts;
    }
        
    public async Task DoPipeline(CancellationToken token)
    {
        int seed = 5;
        int BufferSize = 50;
        var buffer1 = new BlockingCollection<string>(BufferSize);

        using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
        var f = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
        var stage1 = f.StartNew(() => ReadStringsFromObservableSourse(buffer1, seed, cts).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        var stage2 = f.StartNew(() => WriteSentences(buffer1, cts).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        await Task.WhenAll(stage1, stage2);
    }
    
    
    private async Task ReadStringsFromObservableSourse(BlockingCollection<string> output, int seed, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        var observableTask= new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            var ct = cts.Token;
            using var observerLifeTime = _ts.GetSourseStringObservable().Take(seed).Subscribe(
                i =>
                {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        observableTask.SetCanceled();
                        return;
                    }
                    output.Add(i, ct);
                },
                e=>
                {     
                    observableTask.SetException(e);
                },
                () =>
                {
                    observableTask.SetResult(default);
                }
            );
            await observableTask.Task.WaitAsync(ct);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();      //нотификация отмены остальным стадиям конвеера.
            if (!(e is OperationCanceledException))
                throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            output.CompleteAdding();
        }
    }
    
    
    private async Task WriteSentences(BlockingCollection<string> input, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        try
        {
            var token = cts.Token;    
            foreach (var phrase in input.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
                await Task.Delay(100);
                var result = phrase + "  Stage_Write";
                Console.WriteLine(result + "   " + DateTime.Now.ToString("T")); //Запись полученного результата
            }
          
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // If an exception occurs, notify all other pipeline stages.
            cts.Cancel(); 
            if (!(e is OperationCanceledException))
                throw;
        }
    }
}


public class TextSource
{
    public IObservable<string> GetSourseStringObservable()
    {
        var sensorFunc = new Func<CancellationToken, Task<string>>((ct) => GetValueFromRemoteSource("Get only new Values", ct));
        var sp= new SensorPolling<string>(sensorFunc);
        var xs=sp.Polling();
        return xs;
    }

    private int i = 0;
    private async Task<string> GetValueFromRemoteSource (string filter, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        //filter not Use
        i++;
        await Task.Delay(500, ct);
        return i.ToString();
    }
}


public class SensorPolling<T>
{
    private readonly Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> _tryTakeDataAsync;

    public SensorPolling(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> tryTakeDataAsync)
    {
        _tryTakeDataAsync = tryTakeDataAsync;
    }
    
    public IObservable<T> Polling()
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(
            (obs, ct) =>
            {
                return Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var data = await _tryTakeDataAsync(ct);
                            obs.OnNext(data);
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            obs.OnCompleted(); 
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            obs.OnError(e);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Loop terminated");
                }, ct);
            });
    }
}
```

P.S. Реализация `ReadStrings` как в примере с офф. сайта получение данных через `IEnumerable`  (`_ts.GetNextString(seed)`).

```
    private async Task ReadStrings(BlockingCollection<string> output, int seed, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        try
        {
            var ct = cts.Token;
            foreach (var phrase in _ts.GetNextString(seed)) 
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
                await Task.Delay(100);
                var result = phrase + " Stage_Read"; //Работа стадии 1
                Console.WriteLine(result  + "   " + DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
                output.Add(result, ct);
                throw new Exception("gfhgdfgfd");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // If an exception occurs, notify all other pipeline stages.
            cts.Cancel(); 
            if (!(e is OperationCanceledException))
                throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            output.CompleteAdding();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я бы вот это `var stage1 = f.StartNew(() => ReadStringsFromObservableSourse(buffer1, seed, cts).GetAwaiter().GetResult())` записал вот так `var stage1 = ReadStringsFromObservableSourse(buffer1, seed, cts)`. Зачем `LongRunning` поток, который даже использоваться не будет, дорого это по ресурсам, и бессмысленно.

Comment: А вообще, конвейер обработки данных - это шаблон программирования Producer/Consumer. А для реализации его асинхронно, есть отличный инструмент - [System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

Comment: А что всё так сложно-то? Есть же метод `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.ForEachAsync`, он уже и `CancellationToken` принимает, и даже `Task` возвращает...

Comment: Кстати, зачем делать конвейер на основе `BlockingCollection`, если `IObservable` - уже конвейер?

Comment: 'BlockingCollection' я хотел локально использовать там где  уже есть последовательный конвейер обработки, заменить его на конвейер  BlockingCollection'.  А Observable  - грубо говоря глобальный сервис поставщик данных для всех сервисов обработки кому надо эти данные. Т.е. самое простое это использовать 'Observable.ForEachAsync'  и городить такой огород без острой нужды не стоит?

Comment: System.Threading.Channels. - почитаю, Спасибо